# replacement for ereg_replace

Tags: php, regex, preg-replace, ereg-replace

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [How can I convert ereg expressions to preg in PHP?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6270004/how-can-i-convert-ereg-expressions-to-preg-in-php)

I have upgraded php and now im getting the `ereg_replace` deprecated errors.

I have done some searching round web and found that I can use preg instead but not sure how to change this code correctly

```
$scriptName = ereg_replace(
    "^".$_SERVER["DOCUMENT_ROOT"], "", 
    $_SERVER["SCRIPT_FILENAME"]
);
```

Comment: @Goran No joke here, folks. Move it along.

Comment: @Linus: A dirty trick, indeed.

Comment: oh come on a replacement for ereg REPLACE?!  good job my main job is not comedy :(

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just adding delimiters won't work when special characters are included in $_SERVER["DOCUMENT_ROOT"]'s value. You need to escape them as follows:

```
$scriptName = preg_replace(
  "/^".preg_quote($_SERVER["DOCUMENT_ROOT"],"/")."/",
  "", 
  $_SERVER["SCRIPT_FILENAME"]
);
```

Comment: cheers @Highly Irregular

Answer (score 6):

Replace the `e` with a `p`.

Add a delimiter to the beginning and end of that first argument. Traditionally, people use slashes (`/`), but I like to use `~` as there is less chance of actually using that character in the regular expression.

Comment: No. That'll not do it. `preg_replace` expects delimiters, whereas `ereg_replace` doesn't. You should rephrase that answer a bit.

Comment: `prpgrpplacp` errors out on my machine. :)

Comment: @Tim That means you have your PHP configured wrong. Open up php.ini in a text editor and find the following line: `la_disparition=` Set it equal to `p`. If you're on a shared host, you can do it on the fly by calling `gadsby('p')`.