# How can I convert ereg expressions to preg in PHP?

Tags: php, preg-replace, preg-match, pcre, ereg

Since [POSIX regular expressions (ereg)](http://php.net/regex) are deprecated since PHP 5.3.0, I'd like to know an easy way to convert the old expressions to [PCRE (Perl Compatible Regular Expressions) (preg)](http://php.net/pcre).

Per example, I have this regular expression:

```
eregi('^hello world');
```

How can I translate expressions into `preg_match` compatible expressions?

> ***Note:* This post serves as a placeholder for all posts related to conversion from ereg to preg, and as a duplicate options for related questions.** Please do not close this question.
>
> **Related:**
>
> - [How to change PHP's eregi to preg_match](https://stackoverflow.com/q/1374881/367456)
> - [Changing ereg_replace to equivalent preg_replace](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6269693/changing-ereg-replace-to-equivalent-preg-replace)

Comment: @yes123: Yes, that's the point, I'm tired of it too. I want a wiki post that actually explains something so we can close all these individual questions.

Comment: I think no need for this because you just need to wrap the old with a delimiter. Also I think you could have used a previous answered question for this.

Comment: Ah, voted for a close before reading the comments. As a placeholder it could serve a purpose, but isn't there another older question that could've served as such?

Comment: Hmm, indeed. `ereg [php]` doesn't yield very much useful results. OK, can lend my support to this one.

Comment: @netcoder: acutally I think I answered almost to everything here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6269693/changing-ereg-replace-to-equivalent-preg-replace/6269720#6269720 not to brag out of course

Comment: Folks, we seem to have nearly created a circle of closed questions on this topic all pointing at each other. At this rate they'll all be closed :)

Answer (score 154, accepted):

The biggest change in the syntax is the addition of [delimiters](http://php.net/manual/en/regexp.reference.delimiters.php).

```
ereg('^hello', $str);
preg_match('/^hello/', $str);
```

Delimiters can be pretty much anything that is not alpha-numeric, a backslash or a whitespace character. The most used are generally `~`, `/` and `#`.

You can also use matching brackets:

```
preg_match('[^hello]', $str);
preg_match('(^hello)', $str);
preg_match('{^hello}', $str);
// etc
```

If your delimiter is found in the regular expression, you have to escape it:

```
ereg('^/hello', $str);
preg_match('/^\/hello/', $str);
```

You can easily escape all delimiters and reserved characters in a string by using [preg_quote](http://php.net/preg_quote):

```
$expr = preg_quote('/hello', '/');
preg_match('/^'.$expr.'/', $str);
```

Also, PCRE supports [modifiers](http://php.net/manual/en/reference.pcre.pattern.modifiers.php) for various things. One of the most used is the case-insensitive modifier `i`, the alternative to [eregi](http://php.net/eregi):

```
eregi('^hello', 'HELLO');
preg_match('/^hello/i', 'HELLO');
```

You can find the complete reference to [PCRE syntax in PHP in the manual](http://php.net/manual/en/pcre.pattern.php), as well as a [list of differences](http://php.net/manual/en/reference.pcre.pattern.posix.php) between POSIX regex and PCRE to help converting the expression.

However, in your simple example you would not use a regular expression:

```
stripos($str, 'hello world') === 0
```

Comment: Wonderful explanation! I'd like just to add an special case in which your are converting from __ereg__ to __preg_match__ and you need to escape only the delimiters and not reserved characters (because they were already working as special characters, we don't want to escape them):  **preg_match('/'.str_replace('/','\/',$expr).'/', $str);**

Comment: It's particularly worth noting that if you use matching brackets, then you *don't* need to escape any characters "just because it's the same as the delimiter" like you do with other symbols like the `/^\/hello/` example. `(a(b)c)` is a perfectly valid, delimited PCRE. I personally like to use parentheses `()` to remind myself that the first captured match is the entire thing.

Comment: how to convert this?            $regex = $e . '((\.[^\.' . $e . '][^' . $e . ']*)|(\.\.[^' . $e . ']+)|([^\.][^' . $e . ']*))' . $e . '\.\.' . $e;      to preg_math it doest work by just adding  / modifier  /

Answer (score 36):

Ereg replacement with preg(as of PHP 5.3.0) was right move in our favor.

preg_match, which uses a Perl-compatible regular expression syntax, is often a faster alternative to ereg.

**You should know 4 main things to port ereg patterns to preg:**

1. **Add delimiters**(/): `'pattern' => '/pattern/'`
2. **Escape delimiter** if it is a part of the pattern: `'patt/ern' => '/patt\/ern/'`
   Achieve it programmatically in following way:
   `$old_pattern = '<div>.+</div>';`
   `$new_pattern = '/' . addcslashes($old_pattern, '/') . '/';`
3. **eregi**(case-insensitive matching): `'pattern' => '/pattern/i'`
   So, if you are using eregi function for case insenstive matching, just add 'i' in the end of new pattern('/pattern/').
4. **ASCII values**: In ereg, if you use number in the pattern, it is assumed that you are referring to the ASCII of a character. But in preg, number is not treated as ASCII value. So, if your pattern contain ASCII value in the ereg expression(for example: new line, tabs etc) then convert it to hexadecimal and prefix it with \x.
   `Example: 9(tab) becomes \x9 or alternatively use \t.`

Answer (score 12):

**From PHP version 5.3, `ereg` is deprecated.**

Moving from `ereg` to `preg_match` is just a small change in our pattern.

First, you have to add delimiters to your code, e.g.:

```
ereg('A-Z0-9a-z', 'string');
```

to

```
preg_match('/A-Z0-9a-z/', 'string');
```

For `eregi` case-insensitive matching, put `i` after the last delimiter, e.g.:

```
eregi('pattern', 'string');
```

to

```
preg_match ('/pattern/i', 'string');
```

Answer (score 7):

There are more differences between `ereg()` and `preg_replace()` than just the syntax:

- Return value:

  - *On error*: both return `FALSE`
  - *On no match*: `ereg()` returns `FALSE`, `preg_match()` returns `0`
  - *On match*: `ereg()` returns string length or `1`, `preg_match()` returns always `1`
- Resulting array of matched substrings: If some substring is not found at all (`(b)` in `...a(b)?`), corresponding item in `ereg()` result will be `FALSE`, while in `preg_match()` it will not be set at all.

If one is not brave enough to convert his or her `ereg()` to `preg_match()`, he or she may use [mb_ereg()](http://php.net/manual/en/function.mb-ereg.php), which is still available in PHP 7.