# ereg is deprecated conversion

Tags: php, regex, preg-match, ereg

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Converting ereg expressions to preg](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6270004/converting-ereg-expressions-to-preg)

I need to convert the ereg usage here to something more current (since ereg is deprecated).

Here's the function my code currently relies on:

```
function ValidEmail($address)
{
    if( ereg( ".*<(.+)>", $address, $regs ) ) {
        $address = $regs[1];
    }

    if(ereg( "^[^@  ]+@([a-zA-Z0-9\-]+\.)+([a-zA-Z0-9\-]{2}|net|com|gov|mil|org|edu|int)\$",$address) ) 
        return true;
    else
        return false;
}
```

As I don't regex - could someone help me convert the function to something that functions the exact same way but isn't using a deprecated function? Thanks.

Comment: Change `ereg` to `preg_match` and check the syntax and options at http://au.php.net/manual/en/function.preg-match.php

Comment: Without knowing regex, I have no idea how to safely convert the regex to something that is preg_match friendly. Simply replacing ereg with preg_match doesn't work - I'm getting unknown modifier errors.

Answer (score 1):

Looks like all I needed to add was switch ereg to preg_match and add a delimiting character to each pattern:

```
function ValidEmail($address)
{
    if( preg_match( "/.*<(.+)>/", $address, $regs ) ) {
        $address = $regs[1];
    }

    if(preg_match( "/^[^@  ]+@([a-zA-Z0-9\-]+\.)+([a-zA-Z0-9\-]{2}|net|com|gov|mil|org|edu|int)\$/",$address) ) 
        return true;
    else
        return false;
}
```