# How to convert ereg() expression to the preg_match() one?

Tags: php, regex

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Converting ereg expressions to preg](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6270004/converting-ereg-expressions-to-preg)

I have this ereg() expression:

```
^[0-9]{8}\T{1}[0-9]{2}\:[0-9]{2}\:[0-9]{2}$
```

How can I convert it to the preg_match one?

Comment: A general rule for ereg->preg is to simply add a delimiter character to the preg version. e.g. `[abc]` for ereg becomes `/[abc]/` for preg, and then if it was eregi, change it to `/[abc]/i` in preg.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The expression looks fine, but you can simplify it:

```
^\d{8}\t\d{2}:\d{2}:\d{2}$
```

Your original one should still work with `preg`, but the one above is simpler to read and understand. A few notes:

- `[0-9]` is the same as `\d`
- `{1}` is unnecessary
- `:` does not need escaping

Answer (score 2):

Here you go.

```
$subject = 'the string i want to search through';
$pattern = '/^[0-9]{8}\T{1}[0-9]{2}\:[0-9]{2}\:[0-9]{2}$/';
$matches = array();
preg_match($pattern, $subject, $matches);

print_r($matches);
```