# eregi_replace() to preg_replace() help

Tags: php, regex, preg-replace, ereg-replace

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Converting ereg expressions to preg](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6270004/converting-ereg-expressions-to-preg)

I've tried this a number of different ways and I've even downloaded the Regular Expression reference sheet from addedbytes.com, but I just can't figure out how to move this eregi_replace() statement into a preg_replace() statement.

I've read and understood the delimiter requirements for preg_replace(), but I think the problem is the modifiers.  How to I know which modifier to use for this function?  I've tried \A, \b, and \e, but none seem to work. I think there's something simply I'm missing.

```
$bodytag = '%%BODY%%';
$header = eregi_replace($bodytag . '.*', '', $temp);
$footer = eregi_replace('.*' . $bodytag, '', $temp);
```

I've tried the following:

```
$header = preg_replace('/%%BODY%%.*/i', '', $temp);
$footer = preg_replace('/.*%%BODY%%/i', '', $temp);
```

But it doesn't seem to work. What am I missing?

EDIT

More recently, I've tried this with no fix.

```
$bodytag = "%%BODY%%";
$header = preg_replace("/".$bodytag."(.*)/i", '', $temp);
$footer = preg_replace("/(.*)".$bodytag."/i", '', $temp);
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

SOLVED:

This turned out to be the solution:

```
$header = preg_replace("/".$bodytag."(.*)/is", '', $temp);
$footer = preg_replace("/(.*)".$bodytag."/is", '', $temp);
```

Got help and the answer from another website's forum.  I was missing the "s" modifier and I also wasn't aware that the modifiers could be stacked.

Answer (score 0):

$header = preg_replace('/BODY(.*)/i', '', $temp);
$footer = preg_replace('/(.*)BODY/i', '', $temp);

Comment: I'm sorry, but that doesn't work in the same way that eregi_replace() performs the process.  Additionally, I need the "%%" symbols to be there since it's replacing the %%BODY%% string in the theme template with the actual contents of the page body.  Furthermore, what are the parenthesis for (why do I need them)?  I'm not asking for someone to just give me the answer, just explain what I'm doing wrong. I'm tired of the depreciated messages in my logs. Thanks!