# Fix deprecated eregi function in php?

Tags: php, function

I'm currently using a function to figure out if a string consists only of numbers. The function `is_numeric` usually works, but if the string contains a letter, it will break. I am trying this instead:

```
function is_signedint($val)
{
    $val = str_replace(" ", "", trim($val));
    //line below is deprecated
    $bool = eregi("^-?([0-9])+$",$val);
    if($bool == 1)
        return true;
    else
        return false;
}
```

Anyways, I was wondering how I could replace the eregi line to comply with PHP6

Comment: possible duplicate of [Converting ereg expressions to preg](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6270004/converting-ereg-expressions-to-preg)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
preg_match("~^-?([0-9])+$~", $val);
```

just add delimiters

Answer (score 0):

```
preg_match("/^-?([0-9])+$/i",$val);
```

case-insensitive `i` as modifier at the end

Comment: case-insensitive as general eregi replacement. wont hurt either

Answer (score 0):

Here's a couple of options

```
if ($val === strval(intval($val)))

if ($val == intval($val))
```

I would use the first method as it checks the value *and* type. You shouldn't use regular expressions unless it is really necessary (or it can squash 10+ lines of code into 1).