# how to replace eregi to preg_match?

Tags: php, preg-match, eregi

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Converting ereg expressions to preg](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6270004/converting-ereg-expressions-to-preg)

I want to change this line with preg_match but it doesn't works.

```
if ($file != "." && $file != ".." && !eregi(".jpg".$thumbext."$",$file) && eregi(".jpg$",$file)){
```

I tried:

```
if ($file != "." && $file != ".." && !preg_match(".jpg".$thumbext."$",$file) && preg_match(".jpg$",$file)){
```

How it should be?

Thanks!

Comment: You might need to show us what is in `$thumbtext`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

preg requires delimiters:

```
preg_match('/.jpg'.$thumbex.'$/',$ile)
```