# PHP-Function ereg_replace() is deprecated

Tags: php

```
class autoActiveLink {

    function makeActiveLink($originalString){

        $newString = ereg_replace("[[:alpha:]]+://[^<>[:space:]]+[[:alnum:]/]","<a href=\"\\0\" target=\"_blank\">\\0</a>", $originalString);
        return $newString;
    }

}
```

What should I replace the function `ereg_replace` with? I tried `preg_replace`, but the error still persists.

Comment: Did you try actually removing the call to `ereg_replace()`?

Comment: possible duplicate of [Converting ereg expressions to preg](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6270004/converting-ereg-expressions-to-preg)

Answer (score 3):

```
preg_replace()
```

http://php.net/manual/en/function.preg-replace.php

**It is not reasonable that the error still exists after you replaced it to preg_replace**

But the pattern syntax is different, youll have to convert it

Answer (score 3):

Try

```
class autoActiveLink {
    function makeActiveLink($originalString){
        $newString = preg_replace('#([A-Za-z]+://[^<>\s]+[A-Za-z0-9/])#','<a href="$1" target="_blank">$1</a>', $originalString);
        return $newString;
    }
}
```