# php 5.3 eregi_replace to preg_replace

Tags: php, mysql, sql

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Converting ereg expressions to preg](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6270004/converting-ereg-expressions-to-preg)

I'm trying to fix some old code so that it works with PHP 5.3.
Hopefully the first conversion to str_replace is okay but I'm completely unsure about the second conversion to preg_replace.

Any help would be very much appreciated. Thanks

```
$this->Query = str_replace(" where "," WHERE ", $this->Query);
$this->Query = str_replace(" select "," SELECT ", $this->Query);
$this->Query = str_replace(" from "," FROM ", $this->Query);
$this->Query = str_replace(" as "," AS ", $this->Query);

// $this->Query = eregi_replace(" WHERE ", " where ", $this->Query);
// $this->Query = eregi_replace("SELECT ", "select ", $this->Query);
// $this->Query = eregi_replace(" FROM ", " from ", $this->Query);
// $this->Query = eregi_replace(" AS ", " as ", $this->Query);

$TempQuery = eregi_replace("^select .* from ", "select count(1) from ", $this->Query);
$TempQuery = eregi_replace(" order by .*$", "", $TempQuery);
```

Comment: you do know that SQL doesn't have to be upper-cased? (and you did the exact opposite of what eregi_replace was doing)

Comment: Refer to the PCRE syntax at http://php.net/manual/en/reference.pcre.pattern.syntax.php

Comment: You can do that with, `preg_replace('/pattern_here/i', 'replacement', $subject)`, but why go through all this hassle? The queries will work either way.

Comment: I was just keeping the code the same and as it had a the comment // retouch query to avoid case matching problems

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As said, SQL syntax doesn't have to be in upper-case... However to answer your question anyway:

```
$TempQuery = preg_replace("/^select .*? from /i", "select count(1) from ", $this->Query);
$TempQuery = preg_replace("/ order by .*?$/i", "", $TempQuery);
```

That should work. I made the regex case-insensitive since you seem to have trouble with upper- and lower-case. Also, I made the `.*` ungreedy by adding a question mark to avoid extra complications.

Answer (score 1):

*eregi_replace* must be replace by *preg_replace*

ex :

```
$string = $this->Query;
$pattern = '/^select .* from /i';
$replacement = "select count(1) from ";
$TempQuery = preg_replace($pattern, $replacement, $string);
```

Comment: Many thanks, seems simple enough adding delimiters and an 'i' at the end. Cheers