# use preg_split instead of split

Tags: php, regex, split, fpdf

I'm using FPDF v. 1.53. Now I switched to a newer PHP version. The function `split` is now deprecated. I had on line 108 the following code in fpdf_eps.php:

```
$lines = split ("\r\n|[\r\n]", $data);
```

I wanted to change it to preg_split

```
$lines = preg_split ("\r\n|[\r\n]", $data);
```

but than the script seems to have an error and I only get the message page not found (I always get this if a script has an error). What is wrong? The regexp?

Comment: Could you try "/\r\n|[\r\n]/"?

Comment: @Eamorr: This is the correct answer, you should post it as such.

Comment: There is no error anymore. Thanks! Now I have to look for another error ;)

Comment: possible duplicate of [Converting ereg expressions to preg](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6270004/converting-ereg-expressions-to-preg)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When using regular expressions with preg, you should contain your regex inside slashes. Your regex should look like this:

```
$lines = preg_split ("/\r\n|[\r\n]/", $data)
                      ^           ^
```

Answer (score 2):

You've missed the trailing `/` aswell as the one in front of the pattern:

```
 $lines = preg_split ("/\r\n|[\r\n]/", $data);
                       ^           ^
```