# split to preg_split

Tags: php, regex, preg-split

This question is very similar to [use preg_split instead of split](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8255422/use-preg-split-instead-of-split) but I've got some confusions with the regex that I'd live to clear up.

Trying to update some existing split() functions to use preg_split() instead and I'm getting some unclear results. Running the code below will give me arrays of different lengths and I'm not sure why.

From what I can see split is matching on \n with a possible \r beforehand.
And I think preg_split is doing the same but then why is it creating 2 splits? Is this to do with lazy/greedy matching?

Demo code :

```
$test = "\r\n";

$val = split('\r?\n', $test); //literal interpretation of string
$val_new = split("\r?\n", $test); //php understanding that these are EOL chars
$val2 = preg_split('/\r?\n/', $test);

var_dump($val); // returns array(1) { [0]=> string(2) " " }
var_dump($val2); // returns array(2) { [0]=> string(0) "" [1]=> string(0) "" }
```

Edit : added in $val_new based on Kolinks comments because they helped clear up my understanding of the problem so may be of use to another too

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`split` does not understand `\r` and `\n` as special characters, and because you used single quotes PHP doesn't treat them as special characters either. So `split` is looking for literal `\\n` or `\r\n`.

`preg_split`, on the other hand, does understand `\r` and `\n` as special characters, so even though PHP doesn't treat them as such PCRE does and the string is therefore split correctly.

This has nothing to do with lazy/greedy matching, it's all because of the single quotes not parsing `\r\n` into their newline meanings.

Comment: Aha, that makes perfect sense now and has helped me solve my problem too. Many thanks for the clear explanation - will mark this as the answer as soon as Im allowed to

Answer (score 2):

You should `PREG_SPLIT_NO_EMPTY` flag as 3rd argument of `preg_split` to ignore empty tokens in the split array. So if you use

```
preg_split('/\r?\n/', $test, PREG_SPLIT_NO_EMPTY);
```

then it will behave same as split function.

And by the way your use of `\r?\n` in split function is not doing any splitting (since split doesn't understand `\r` and `\n` in single quotes) and returning your **original string** back.

*Edit:* Alternatively you can use split with double quotes regex:

```
split("\r?\n", $test);
```

to split your string into 2 elements array.

Comment: It was in the middle of some edits, pls check it now for better explanation.

Comment: Still wrong, especially since [`split()`](http://php.net/split) is specifically defined as "Split string into array ***by regular expression***"

Comment: Ah yes you're right, making corrections now. Thanks for pointing it.

Comment: Thanks, that does indeed make it match the same and made me go read up on it