# PHP Regular Expression Failing

Tags: php, regex

My current regular expression should be correct, though I wouldn't expect so, it doesn't work properly. It won't return "Got Match"
My currrent code is as follows:

```
$id = "http://steamcommunity.com/id/TestID";
    if (preg_match("^http://steamcommunity\.com/id/.*?\n$", $id)) {
        print "Got match!\n";
    }
```

Comment: possible duplicate of [Converting ereg expressions to preg](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6270004/converting-ereg-expressions-to-preg)

Answer (score 4):

You're missing delimiters on your regex:

```
if (preg_match("#^http://steamcommunity\.com/id/.*?\n$#", $id)) {
                ^--here                               ^--here
```

Note that I've used `#` as the delimiter here, since that saves you having to escape all of the internal `/` charrs, if you'd used the traditional `/` as the delimiter.

Comment: +1. I know that's possible in perl, and use it quite often, but I didn't know that it's possible in php too. I've hardly ever used php though. Regarding the question, there's also the newline he's trying to match against.

Comment: preg is "perl-compatible" and implements almost everything that you can do in perl regexes.

Comment: Yeah, but I've thought of the delimiters as more of language syntax than part of the regex. I see that it's not though, as it's often part of a regex string with optional flags after the closing delimiter.

Answer (score 3):

You need a delimiter, like this:

```
if (preg_match("#^http://steamcommunity\.com/id/.*?$#", $id)) {
                ^                                   ^
```

And what's with the newline at the end? Surely you don't need that.

Comment: You've forgotten to escape the `/` inside the url, which is required if you use `/` as the delimiter.

Comment: i edited the post ten seconds ago to use a different delimiter

Answer (score 2):

You're missing [delimiters](http://www.php.net/manual/en/regexp.reference.delimiters.php). For example:

```
"#^http://steamcommunity\.com/id/.*?\n$#"
```

Also, you're trying to match a newline (`\n`) that isn't in your string.

Answer (score 2):

You need to add the pattern delimiter:

```
$id = "http://steamcommunity.com/id/TestID";
if (preg_match("#^http://steamcommunity\.com/id/.*?(\n|$)#", $id)) {
   print "Got match!\n";
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You need to have starting and ending delimiter in your pattern like `/pattern/` or `#pattern#` or with brackets `(pattern)`. Why is that? To have some pattern modifiers after ending delimiter like `#pattern#i` (ignore case)

```
preg_match('(^http://steamcommunity\.com/id/.*?\n$)', $id)
```

Answer (score 1):

There are a couple of things that are wrong with it. First of all, you need to delimit the start and end of your regex with a character. I used `#`. You're also matching for a new line at the end of your regex, which you don't have and likely won't ever have in your string.

```
<?php
    $id = "http://steamcommunity.com/id/TestID";
    if (preg_match("#^http://steamcommunity\.com/id/.*?$#", $id)) {
        print "Got match!\n";
    }
?>
```

http://codepad.viper-7.com/L7XctT

Answer (score 1):

First of all, your regex shouldn't even compile because it's missing delimiters.

```
if (preg_match("~^http://steamcommunity\.com/id/.*?\n$~", $id)) {
                ^----      these guys here       -----^
```

Second of all, why do you have a `\n` if your string doesn't contain a new line?

And finally, why are you using regex at all? Effectively, you are just trying to match a constant string. This should be equivalent to what you are trying to match:

```
if (strpos($id, 'http://steamcommunity.com/id/') === 0) {
```

Comment: Good point, though I figured the logical next step was to capture the ID code from that string with a subpattern.

Answer (score 0):

As the say your patten is start and end wrong. (Delimiter)
But this will be a better match of a 64-bit Steam ID. (Minimum 17 and Maximum 25 numbers)

```
if( preg_match("#^http://steamcommunity\.com/id/([0-9]{17,25})#i", $id, $matches) )
{
    echo "Got match! - ".$matches;
}
```

I believe that there is no need for you to require that the string must end with a line break.

**Explanation.**

```
http://steamcommunity\.com/id/([0-9]{17,25})
^---       string         ---^^-- Regexp --^
```

[0-9] - Match a number between 0 to 9
{17,25} - Make 17 to 25 matches
() - Returns match

Or use pattern as those (It is the same):

```
/^http:\/\/steamcommunity\.com\/id\/([0-9]{17,25})/i
(^http://steamcommunity\.com/id/([0-9]{17,25}))i
```

[Regular Expressions PHP Tutorial](http://weblogtoolscollection.com/regex/regex.php)
[Online regular expression testing](http://gskinner.com/RegExr/) <- Dont use delimiter.

Answer (score -2):

```
<?php
  # URL that generated this code:
  # http://txt2re.com/index-php.php3?s=http://steamcommunity.com/id&-1

  $txt='http://steamcommunity.com/id';

  $re1='(http:\\/\\/steamcommunity\\.com\\/id)';    # HTTP URL 1

  if ($c=preg_match_all ("/".$re1."/is", $txt, $matches))
  {
      $httpurl1=$matches[1][0];
      print "($httpurl1) \n";
  }

  #-----
  # Paste the code into a new php file. Then in Unix:
    # $ php x.php 
  #-----
?>
```

Resorces:
http://txt2re.com/index.php3?s=http://steamcommunity.com/id&-1

Comment: Why is there a perl answer to a php question?