# Switching from ereg_replace to preg_replace

Tags: php, preg-replace, php-5.3

I have an application that is now running on PHP 5.3 that was originally developed in a previous version.  I receive an eror stating:

> Function `ereg_replace()` is deprecated

referring to the following snippet:

```
<?php $summary = ereg_replace("<[^>]*>","", $item['item_description'])?>
```

What changes to the above snippet are required to use `preg_replace()`?

Comment: * [converting ereg to preg (missing regex delimiters)](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6270004/converting-ereg-expressions-to-preg)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

All you need to do is use the function [`preg_replace()`](http://php.net/preg_replace) and put delimiters around the expression:

```
$summary = preg_replace("/<[^>]*>/","", $item['item_description']);
```

Answer (score 0):

And for eregi_replace use:

```
$summary = preg_replace("/<[^>]*>/i","", $item['item_description']);
```

Consider the **i** modifier.