# Error escaping quotes in regular expressions in PHP

Tags: php, regex, escaping, preg-replace

I am new to PHP and trying to replace a URL pattern with google.com in the code below.

```
    $textStr = "Test string contains http://foo.com/more_(than)_one_(parens)
http://foo.com/blah_(wikipedia)#cite-1
http://foo.com/blah_(wikipedia)_blah#cite-1
http://foo.com/unicode_(?)_in_parens
http://foo.com/(something)?after=parens
more urls foo.ca/me some other text";

$pattern = '(?i)\b((?:https?://|www\d{0,3}[.]|[a-z0-9.\-]+[.][a-z]{2,4}/)((?:[^\s()<>]+|\(([^\s()<>]+|(\([^\s()<>]+\)))*\))+(?:\(([^\s()<>]+|(\([^\s()<>]+\)))*\)|[^\s`!()\[\]{};:\'".,<>?«»“”‘’]))*)';

$textStr = preg_replace($pattern, "google.com", $textStr); 

echo $textStr;
```

I found the regular expression pattern at http://daringfireball.net/2010/07/improved_regex_for_matching_urls but I have not been able to escape the single quote, double quotes in the pattern successfully.

Currently I get the message -- Warning: preg_replace() Unknown modifier '\'
But I used the slash() to escape the single quote in {};:\'"

Can someone please help me with the code above?

Comment: possible duplicate of [Converting ereg expressions to preg (missing delimiters)](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6270004/converting-ereg-expressions-to-preg)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In the first place for `preg_replace` you have to delimit your regular expression by `/`, as in:

```
/\b((?:https: ... etc etc)/
```

Second, since you delimit your regular expressions with `/` you have to escape any `/` with a backslash. So `https://` -> `https:\/\/`.

Third, your modifiers `(?i)` go after the trailing slash:

```
`/\b((?:https: .. etc etc)/i`
```

Try (changes made: escaped `/`, moved regex from  `(?i)regex` to `/regex/i`):

```
$pattern = '/\b((?:https?:\/\/|www\d{0,3}[.]|[a-z0-9.\-]+[.][a-z]{2,4}\/)((?:[^\s()<>]+|\(([^\s()<>]+|(\([^\s()<>]+\)))*\))+(?:\(([^\s()<>]+|(\([^\s()<>]+\)))*\)|[^\s`!()\[\]{};:\'".,<>?«»“”‘’]))*)/i';
$textStr = preg_replace($pattern, "google.com", $textStr); 

echo $textStr;
```

Now, since `$pattern` matches the entire URL you will just get out:

```
"Test string contains google.com
google.com
google.com
google.com
google.com
more urls google.com some other text"
```

so all in all, I recommend either @Ampere's answer (but this has a looser regex than your original), or using capturing brackets and backreferences to do something like `preg_replace($pattern,'google.com/\2',$textStr)` (but modify your capturing brackets appropriately, as this will not work with your current capturing bracket arrangement).

[This site](http://www.solmetra.com/scripts/regex/index.php) is useful for testing things out.

Comment: The regex delimiter doesn't have to be `/`, it can be almost any punctuation character.  For example, if you use `~` you won't have to escape anything because that character never appears in the regex.  Also, PHP does support the `(?i)` (inline modifier) syntax, so you don't have to change that (but trailing modifiers work, too).

Answer (score 1):

```
$patterrn='/([wW]{3,3}\.|)[A-Za-z0-9]+?\./';
$text="Test string contains http://foo.com/more_(than)_one_(parens)
http://foo.com/blah_(wikipedia)#cite-1
http://foo.com/blah_(wikipedia)_blah#cite-1
http://foo.com/unicode_(?)_in_parens
http://foo.com/(something)?after=parens
more urls foo.ca/me some other text";
$output = preg_replace($patterrn,"abc.",$text);
print_r($output);
```

the output will be ,

```
Test string contains http://abc.com/more_(than)_one_(parens) http://abc.com/blah_(wikipedia)#cite-1 http://abc.com/blah_(wikipedia)_blah#cite-1 http://abc.com/unicode_(?)_in_parens http://abc.com/(something)?after=parens more urls abc.ca/me some other text
```

Comment: Thank you for your help. While I can't use this for my current needs, this will definitely be handy in other situations.