# How to correctly replace ereg with preg

Tags: preg-match, eregi

I have a list of Mobile devices that I'm using to display content correctly. The depreciated function looks like this:

```
function detectPDA($query){
    $browserAgent = $_SERVER['HTTP_USER_AGENT'];
    $userAgents = $this->getBrowserAgentsToDetect(); // comma separated list of devices
    foreach ( $userAgents as $userAgent ) {
        if(eregi($userAgent,$browserAgent)){
            if(eregi("iphone",$browserAgent) || eregi("ipod",$browserAgent) ){
                $this->iphone = true;
            }else{
                $this->pda = true;
            }
        }
    }
}
```

What is the correct way to replace the eregi functions?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How can I convert ereg expressions to preg in PHP?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6270004/how-can-i-convert-ereg-expressions-to-preg-in-php)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If all the pattern strings (`$userAgent` and `iphone`) can be trusted not to contain special regex chars (`()[]!|.^${}?*+`), then you just surround the `eregi` regex with slashes (`/`) and add an `i` after the last slash (which means "case insensitive").

So:

```
eregi($userAgent,$browserAgent) --> preg_match("/$userAgent/i",$browserAgent)
eregi("iphone",$browserAgent)   --> preg_match('/iphone/i',$browserAgent)
```

However, are you just trying to match `$userAgent` as-is within `$browserAgent`? For example, if a particular `$userAgent` was `foo.bar`, would you want the `.` to match a literal period, or would you want to interpret it in its regex sense ("match any character")?

If the former, I'd suggest you forgo regex entirely and use [`stripos($haystack,$needle)`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.stripos.php), which searches for the string `$needle` in `$haystack` (case-insensitive). Then you don't need to worry about (say) an asterisk in `$userAgent` being interpreted in the regex sense instead of the literal sense.

If you do use `stripos` don't forget it can return a `0` which would evaluate to `false`, so you need to use `=== false` or `!== false` (see the documentation I linked).

Comment: thanks for the response - also the note on interpretation of the regex.. most useful.