# Check the hostname with preg_match

Tags: php, regex

I have a problem using preg_match.  (I'm very new to regular expressions)

```
if(preg_match('^/http:\/\/myWebsite\.com\/', $_SERVER['HTTP_REFERER'])) {
return true;
}
else{
return false;
}
```

Always returns false and it shouldn't.  Where am I wrong?

UPDATE

Hi everybody ! Thanks all of you for your help ! Every check is fine now

Comment: You need to configure PHP to display errors. That way you'll see: `Warning: preg_match(): No ending delimiter`

Comment: 1) Why not look at available patterns, 2) You don't use case insensitive matching. 3) Delimiter 4) Is the referer always http, https? might be more suited

Comment: * [converting ereg to preg (missing regex delimiters)](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6270004/converting-ereg-expressions-to-preg)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your regular expression is missing the delimiters, as PHP should have warned you:

```
$_SERVER['HTTP_REFERER'] = 'http://myWebsite.com/foo.html';
var_dump( preg_match('^/http:\/\/myWebsite\.com\/', $_SERVER['HTTP_REFERER']) );
```

... triggers:

> Warning: preg_match(): No ending delimiter

Since you are allowed to choose your own delimiter, it's simpler to pick one that's not in the text:

```
preg_match('@^http://myWebsite\.com/@', $_SERVER['HTTP_REFERER'])
```

Additionally, if the text is not fixed (not this case I presume), PHP can escape it for you:

```
preg_match('/^' . preg_quote('http://myWebsite.com/', '/') . '/', $_SERVER['HTTP_REFERER'])
```

I suggest you configure your development box to display all possible errors. You have several ways to do so:

1. Edit your `php.ini`file:

   ```
   error_reporting = E_ALL | E_STRICT
   display_errors = On
   ```
2. Put this on top of your script:

   ```
   <?php

   error_reporting(E_ALL | E_STRICT);
   ini_set('display_errors', TRUE);
   ```
3. If PHP runs as Apache module, you can also use an `.htaccess` file:

   ```
   # Print E_ALL | E_STRICT from a PHP script to get the appropriate number:
   php_value error_reporting 2147483647
   php_flag display_errors on
   ```

Comment: Thank you very much for taking time to help me ! Everything runs smooth now ! Thanks again.

Answer (score 1):

```
return (boolean) preg_match('#^http://myWebsite\.com/#i', $_SERVER['HTTP_REFERER']);
```

You can choose your own delimiter to make things easier. Here I've chosen `#`.

I also added an `i` modifier at the end to make the search case-insensitive.

I removed the if/else branches and just returned the result of `preg_match` (type-casted to boolean).

Comment: +1 for using #. I find I rarely use them in regex and hence no need to escape, and they stand out from the thorny spike look of the rest of the regex.

Comment: Thank you very much for taking time to help me ! The i parameter is really handy ! Thanks a lot.

Answer (score 0):

It should be `'/^http:\/\/myWebsite\.com\//i'` (note the caret (^) position, and the i for case-insensitive matching)

Answer (score 0):

preg_match requires a valid delimiter. It may be throwing a warning that you aren't seeing. You should place the carat ^ after the opening /.

Also try `error_reporting(E_ALL);` to see any warnings etc.