# Simple preg match pattern

Tags: php, regex, preg-match

Please can someone help me out with the expression required for the following:

A $content variable holds a block of HTML and I want to match it against a string that could contain any ID. So I am looking for `<p>###GALLERY(ANY NUMBER HERE)###</p>`

This is the code I have already that doesn't work (sorry new to regex):

```
if (preg_match("<p>###GALLERY[0-9]###</p>", $content))
{
    // Found
}
```

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: what's any number? always just one digit?

Comment: Could be 5, could be 3345863948563. The + quantifier that Tim Cooper mentioned solves this :-)

Comment: possible duplicate of [Converting ereg expressions to preg](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6270004/converting-ereg-expressions-to-preg)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You need to include [delimiters](http://php.net/manual/regexp.reference.delimiters.php) in your expression:

```
if (preg_match("/<p>###GALLERY[0-9]###<\/p>/", $content))
```

I'm not sure if you need this, but adding a [`+` quantifier](http://php.net/manual/regexp.reference.meta.php) after `[0-9]` will allow for multi-digit numbers:

```
if (preg_match("/<p>###GALLERY[0-9]+###<\/p>/", $content))
```

Comment: If it's more than just one or two digits, you may want to use * instead. `[0-9]*`

Comment: this works? doesn't it have to be two back slashes to escape that forward slash? i'd rather use a different delimiter character at this point, say %

Comment: I did use a different delimiter, but then I noticed Tim Cooper had added an escaping slash which is why it worked. Thanks for the * Paul that will ne handy