# eregi to regex conversion while downloading youtube file

Tags: php, regex, url, youtube

I am using this code to download video from you tube (it is a robot.php file used in downloading process)

```
<?php
header("Cache-Control: no-cache, must-revalidate"); // HTTP/1.1
header("Expires: Sat, 26 Jul 1997 05:00:00 GMT"); // Date in the past

require_once('lib/youtube.lib.php');
if(eregi('youtube.com|localhost',$_GET['url'])){
    if(!eregi('www.',$_GET['url'])){
        $_GET['url'] = str_replace('http://','http://www.',$_GET['url']);
    }
    list($video_id,$download_link) = get_youtube($_GET['url']);
            ?>
    <p>
    <img src="http://img.youtube.com/vi/<?php echo trim($video_id);?>/1.jpg" alt="Preview 1" class="ythumb" />
    <img src="http://img.youtube.com/vi/<?php echo trim($video_id);?>/2.jpg" alt="Preview 2" class="ythumb" />
    <img src="http://img.youtube.com/vi/<?php echo trim($video_id);?>/3.jpg" alt="Preview 3" class="ythumb" />
    </p>
    <p>
    <a href="<?php echo trim($download_link);?>" class="ydl" title="Download as FLV">Download FLV</a>
    <a href="<?php echo trim($download_link);?>&fmt=18" class="ydl" title="Download as MP4">Download MP4</a>
    <a href="<?php echo trim($download_link);?>&fmt=17" class="ydl" title="Download as 3GP">Download 3GP</a>
    </p>
    <?php
}
else{
    die('<span style="color:red;">Sorry, the URL is not recognized..</span>');
}
?>
```

running this, I get error

> Deprecated: Function eregi() is deprecated in
>   D:\wamp\www\u\code\robot.php on line 6

and line 6 is

> if(eregi('youtube.com|localhost',$_GET['url']))

searching stackoverflow i got

```
if (!function_exists('eregi')) {
        function eregi($find, $str) {
            return stristr($str, $find);
        }
    }
```

but i am not sure how to use it? where should i place it?

could any one help me regarding this? how to update this code to match regex and remove errors?

thanks..

Comment: possible duplicate of [Converting ereg expressions to preg](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6270004/converting-ereg-expressions-to-preg)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As of PHP 5.3.0, the POSIX Regex extension is deprecated in favour of the PCRE extension.

See http://php.net/reference.pcre.pattern.posix for a short overview on migrating your POSIX regex code (`ereg*`) to use the PCRE (`preg_*`) functions, necessary alterations to your regular expressions and limitations of both extensions.

---

Also, you should not use the code that you found.  The PHP error is stating that the function exists but is deprecated. The code that you found will do nothing to help.

---

An *example* of a common "conversion" might look like:

**POSIX** `if (eregi('apple|pear')) …`

**PCRE** `if (preg_match('/apple|pear/i')) …`

What was done?

- Matching function changed from `eregi()` to [`preg_match()`](http://php.net/preg_match).
- Regular expression [*pattern delimiters*](http://php.net/regexp.reference.delimiters) were added.
- [*Pattern modifier*](http://php.net/reference.pcre.pattern.modifiers) `i` (PCRE_CASELESS) was used (to match case-insensitively).

Comment: thanks, can you explain it a bit more? what should i do? i do want to try this code and want to download youtube video using this code?

Comment: I was referring to the code that you found on stackoverflow, the part with `function_exists()`. As for explaining it, read the link. The solution is to use alternative functions instead of `eregi()`, such as `preg_match()` and `strpos()`.

Comment: if(eregi('youtube.com|localhost',$_GET['url'])){
    if(!eregi('www.',$_GET['url'])){
        $_GET['url'] = str_replace('http://','http://www.',$_GET['url']);
    }
    list($video_id,$download_link) = get_youtube($_GET['url']);                     can you convert this code to regex please?

Comment: Please utilize the resources mentioned above and you will be able to do it yourself easily.

Comment: thanks for the guideline ...<br>[link]http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8977169/youtube-video-download-in-php-using-regex please visit this one too

Answer (score 1):

As mentioned by salathe, ereg functions are deprecated now, hence the deprecated notice. Use `preg_match` function instead (you could also hide showing notices, but this won't solve the cause, it will just hide it). The `preg_match` function has a little bit bit different syntax than `eregi`.

Replace line

```
if(eregi('youtube.com|localhost',$_GET['url'])){
```

with

```
if(preg_match('/youtube\.com|localhost/i',$_GET['url'])){
```

Note the `i` at the end of the pattern indicating the match should be case insensitive. You also have to escape the `.`, since this is special regexp character.