# Grab text between specific tags in PHP file

Tags: php, regex, tags, file-get-contents, preg-match-all

Sorry if this question has already been answered elsewhere.  I looked through stack overflow and couldn't find exactly what I was looking for.

I need to know how to scan multiple php files in a single directory (test/ for example), and extract text between specific "tagged" areas on each php file.

Example of "tagged" areas:

```
<?
/*
{('test1')}
*/
?>

<div>text here</div>

<?
/*
{('test2')}
*/
?>
```

And the code would display test1, test2, etc. and ignore anything else.  I tried looking into fopen(), file_get_contents and preg_match_all but each time they only find the first occurrence and not every occurrence of the "tagged" areas.  Any help would be great!

EDIT - WHAT I CURRENTLY HAVE:

```
foreach (glob("templates/*.php") as $fn) {

$file = file_get_contents($fn);

preg_match_all("#\{\('(\w+)'\)}#", $file, $matches);   

$variable = join('', $matches[1]);

echo $variable.'<br />';
```

How do I add array_chunk to this so that each iteration of test is echo'd as it's own variable instead of grouped into an array.  I tried this:

```
$variable = array_chunk($matches[1],1);
```

with no success, it just prints "Array".  any help would be great things.  I will post in a new question if I don't get a response.

Comment: Most fiddly 'tag' syntax conceivable. Is that a real example? But you could show the code that you have so far. `preg_match_all` specifically should find all occurences at once.

Comment: I have included what I am working on so far.

Comment: Both `{` and `(` are regex meta characters. They need escaping. And you need distinct [pcre delimiters](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6270004/converting-ereg-expressions-to-preg). And just to clear this up, you don't actually want to extract the HTMLish parts in between the `{('abc')}` areas? (Else please explain with a supposed output array how you wanted to extract.)

Comment: I do want to grab the text between the {(' ')} areas and echo it

Comment: do you `echo` $variable? it's an Array, that's why it shows as output `Array`. `print_r($variable)` to see the contents.

Comment: Can I then wrap that in the array chunk?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is how you would escape the regex:

```
foreach (glob("template/*.php") as $fn) {

    $file = file_get_contents($fn);

    preg_match_all("#\{\('(\w+)'\)}#", $file, $matches);   

    print_r($matches);

}
```

Eugen has shown how to match the PHP/PI `<?` tags  and `/*` comment sections as well. You may just need `\s*` in between those.

Comment: Parse error: syntax error, unexpected '(' in blahblahblah, error appears on preg_match_all line.

Comment: There was a string syntax mismatch, copied from your example, as shown by the syntax highlighting. Try again.

Comment: Sorry I am very new to this, with no formal education.  got this:
Warning: preg_match_all() [function.preg-match-all]: Compilation failed: unmatched parentheses at offset 11

Comment: Oh well, it seems I need some formal education too.... The closing parenthesis needs escaping too.

Comment: Ah success, it is printing out the array, how would I get it to simply echo the words test1 and test2.  I tried echo $matches; and it only printed the word Array.

Comment: You can `print_r($matches[1])` or use `join(" ", $m[1])` to make it into a list.

Comment: Or, how would I go about storing the text into a variable?  And echoing that variable, based on what you provided as your answer?  Sorry for the back n forth.

Comment: `$variable = join( ... );` and then `echo $variable;` later.

Comment: You are awesome mario thank you for shortening my insanity and days of digging through google and stack overflow.

Comment: Regarding the regex you might also be interested in: [Open source RegexBuddy alternatives](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/89718/is-there) and [Online regex testing](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/32282/regex-testing) for some helpful tools, or [RegExp.info](http://regular-expressions.info/) for a better introduction than with the PHP manual.

Comment: Is there any way to store each occurrence of test in a variable so when echoed it comes out as <br />test1<br />test2<br />test3 etc. instead of it coming out as <br />test1 test2 test3 <br />?  It's echoing the array, so if I were to store these words (test1, test2, test3) into a table, it would create a column called test1 test2 test3.  Instead I would like each test word to be echoed on its own, make sense or no?

Comment: Many options. Either collect them in an array. Or use `nl2br()` or even `join("<br>", $matches[1])` right away.

Comment: The reason I ask, is that I would like to add columns to a table.  Each column name would be the text grabbed from in-between the {('')} areas.  So the first column would be test1 the second column test2 and so on and so forth.  So that's why I need to break each array apart into individual pieces.  Make sense?  If there is a resource to point me at that would be great to.

Comment: Well, you already have an array. Splitting it up is as simple as [`array_chunk()`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.array-chunk.php) for even parts.

Comment: How would I apply array_chunk to this situation, since I don't have a written out array.

Answer (score 0):

```
$filepattern='test/*.php';
$tagpattern='/\<\?\n\/\*\n\{\(\'([^\']+)\'\)\}\n\*\/\n\?\>/';

$files=glob($filepattern);
foreach ($files as $file) {
  $content=file_get_contents($file);
  $count=preg_match_all($tagpattern,$content,$matches);
  if ($count<1) continue;

  //Whatever you want to do with the matches!
  foreach ($matches[1] as $match) echo "$file: $match\n";
}
```

Comment: I can't get your regex to work, however this does: `#<?\s*/\*\s*\{\(\'(.*?)\'\)\}\s*\*/#`

Comment: I tested it localy here and it worked like a charm. Maybe you have \r\n instead of \n?

Answer (score -1):

Regex is unsuitable and slow for this. try php dom or this nice library

http://simplehtmldom.sourceforge.net/