# change ereg to preg_match oscommerce

Tags: php, html, apache

Hi all I have a question with a obsolete/deprecated function.

I need to change `ereg` to `preg_match`

the code with the function is this: http://pastebin.com/jMBkJSEr

I tired to change `ereg` to `preg_match` but it doesn't work by just changing the name of the function.

Comment: In which funtion in oscommerce tep_sanitize_string ??

Comment: possible duplicate of [Converting ereg expressions to preg](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6270004/converting-ereg-expressions-to-preg)

Comment: yes is oscommerce the problem is on advanced_search_result.php on line 306

Comment: You should probably get into contact with the OSCommerce community and solve the problem collectively. I guess you're not the only one with the problem and it might have been solved already.

Answer (score 2):

in addition to those outlined above, there is also eregi that must be updated, which is just a case insensitive version of ereg.  So, replace it with the preg_match and the 'i' switch to make it case insensitive.

Change eregi

> eregi('RegExp', $x)

to preg_match (note the "i" after the second /)

> preg_match('/RegExp/i', $x)

Answer (score 1):

You need to change :

```
function tep_sanitize_string($string) {
        $string = ereg_replace(' +', ' ', trim($string));

        return preg_replace("/[<>]/", '_', $string);
}
```

to

```
function tep_sanitize_string($string) {
        $string = preg_replace('{ +}', ' ', trim($string));

        return preg_replace("/[<>]/", '_', $string);
}
```

There are also many other ereg_replace calls that you might find:

```
ereg_replace('2037' . '$', $year, date(DATE_FORMAT, mktime($hour, $minute, $second, $month, $day, 2037)));
ereg_replace('"', ' ', $pieces[$k]);
ereg_replace('(' . implode('|', $from) . ')', $to, $string);
ereg_replace('[^0-9]', '', $number);
ereg_replace('-language', '-' . $languages[$j]['directory'], $cached_file);
ereg_replace('(' . implode('|', $from) . ')', $to, $string);
ereg_replace("\r","",$which_text);
ereg_replace('-language', '-' . $language, $cache_blocks[$i]['file']);
ereg_replace(",\n$", '', $schema);
ereg_replace("\n#", "\n".'\#', $row);
ereg_replace(', $', '', $schema);
```

You should change these to

```
preg_replace('{2037\z}', $year, date(DATE_FORMAT, mktime($hour, $minute, $second, $month, $day, 2037)));
str_replace('"', ' ', $pieces[$k]);
preg_replace('{(' . implode('|', $from) . ')}', $to, $string);
preg_replace('{\D}', '', $number);
str_replace('-language', '-' . $languages[$j]['directory'], $cached_file);
str_replace("\r","",$which_text);
str_replace('-language', '-' . $language, $cache_blocks[$i]['file']);
preg_replace("{,\n\z}", '', $schema);
preg_replace("{\n#}", "\n".'\#', $row);
preg_replace('{, \z}', '', $schema);
```

Hope this is what you want

EDIT :

There is only one change:

```
ereg('RegExp', $x $y);
```

to

```
preg_match('/RegExp/', $x $y);
```

Same for “ereg_replace”

```
ereg_replace('RegExp', $x, $y);
```

to

```
preg_replace('/RegExp/', $x, $y);
```

Hope you get it.

EDIT:

Also the split is depreciated . You should change:

```
$pieces = split('[[:space:]]+', $search_str);
```

to

```
$pieces = preg_split("/[\s,]+/", $search_str);
```

Hope these things helps you

Comment: thanks , but  yesterday i do this changes,  today the error is http://pastebin.com/r31FeqZH

Answer (score 0):

The new version of oscommerce has changed `eregi` to `preg_match`

```
eregi('eregi data here ', $x)
preg_match('/here your eregi data/', $x)
```