# preg_match warning

Tags: preg-match, eregi

I have deprecated "eregi" problem.

```
if (eregi("data/cheditor4[^<>]*\.(gif|jp[e]?g|png|bmp)", $edit_img, $tmp))
```

So I changed into this,

```
if (preg_match("/data/cheditor4[^<>]*\.(gif|jp[e]?g|png|bmp)/i", $edit_img,$tmp))
```

But I got new warmingmessage,

```
Warning: preg_match() [function.preg-match]: Unknown modifier 'c'
```

Please let me know what is wrong.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How can I convert ereg expressions to preg in PHP?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6270004/how-can-i-convert-ereg-expressions-to-preg-in-php)

Answer (score 3):

You have a '/' inside your regex ('data/cheditor') but you are also using '/' as the regex delimiter ('/myregex/flags'): you can either escape the internal '/', or use a different regex delimiter.

E.g. first option:

```
preg_match('/data\/cheditor4[^<>]*\.(gif|jp[e]?g|png|bmp)/i',...
```

or (second option, I chose '@' as the delimiter):

```
preg_match('@data/cheditor4[^<>]*\.(gif|jp[e]?g|png|bmp)@i',...
```

Also note I changed the " around your regex to ' because otherwise you need to double the backslashes within double-quotes in PHP.

Comment: Thanks a lot. I'll take second option.