# preg_replace regex requires forward slash open and close?

Tags: php, regex, preg-replace

I'm trying to learn regular expressions. I was testing myself by trying to check an email account. The problem though is it's coming up with an error:

No ending delimiter '^' found in /www/eh11522/public_html/scclib/demo/regex.php on line 8

Here is my code:

```
<?php
$pattern = "^([\w.]+)@w([\w.]+).([\w.]+)";
$email = "tyler@surazinet";

if (!preg_replace($pattern, '', $subject)) {
echo "worked";
} else {
echo "failed";
}

?>
```

I found that it will work if I put a slash before and after the pattern, but I don't quite understand what that does, and that doesn't quite match what I want it to.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Converting ereg expressions to preg](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6270004/converting-ereg-expressions-to-preg)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The slashes are delimiters and are required changing

```
$pattern = "^([\w.]+)@w([\w.]+).([\w.]+)";
```

to

```
$pattern = "/^([\w.]+)@w([\w.]+).([\w.]+)/";
```

Will fix your problem. You need to specify a delimiter for the regex. In this case i used `/` but there are lots of [alternatives you can use](http://php.net/manual/en/regexp.reference.delimiters.php). [Info here](http://www.regular-expressions.info/php.html) on using regular expressions with PHP

Answer (score 2):

Your delimiter doesn't have to be a slash in PHP, but you do need to *something* to tell the function where the regular expression starts and ends. Both the slash ('/') and hash symbol (`#`) are popular alternatives; I generally prefer the latter as it allows me to be sloppy when parsing URLs.

```
$pattern = "#^([\w.]+)@w([\w.]+).([\w.]+)#";
```

Answer (score 1):

The slashes are a "masking character" to tell `preg_replace()` what is the beginning and the end of your regular expression. There are a couple of flags you can put in the very end of a RegEx (i.e. after the second masking character) to make it case insensitive, for instance.

Answer (score 1):

The forward slashes are regex delimiters. You can also use other chars as delimiters such as `{pattern}`, `#pattern#`. They are sort of a holdover from other languages such as perl, where you don't need to enclose your regex in quotes for example:

"apples pears oranges" =~ /pears/

They are also used to separate out parts of the regex. For exmaple when you want case interactivity, or to replace some chars: `/pattern/replace/flags`

```
//This perl code will replace Earth, earth, eArth... with zeus
"Earth, mars, mercury, pluto" =~ s/earth/zeus/i;
```