# Regular expression for stock symbol validation (like goog, qqq, ibm, c etc.)

Tags: php, regex

I am using the below expression for checking the stock symbol whether it is valid or not

```
$s_optionPattern = "/^[a-z0-9]{1,6}\s+(?:c|call|p|put)\s+[0-9\.]+\s+[0-9]{4}[0-9]{2}[0-9]{2}$/i";

$s_symbol   =   "TQNT CALL 6 20120519";
$s_symbol2  =   "BRK'B CALL 80 20120317";
echo "<br>--->".preg_match($s_optionPattern, $s_symbol);
echo "<br>--->".preg_match($s_optionPattern, $s_symbol2);
```

Here I am getting false (0) for second symbol and true for first symbol.

Is it correct if i edit the regular expression in the following manner.

```
$s_optionPattern = "/^[a-z0-9']{1,6}\s+(?:c|call|p|put)\s+[0-9\.]+\s+[0-9]{4}[0-9]{2}[0-9]{2}$/i";
```

But I am not sure it is correct or not. Can any body help me to fix this issue ?

Here some stock symbols have (dot,') characters also like BRK.B, BRK'B.

Comment: It's also lacking PCRE delimiters, see manual or: possible duplicate of [converting ereg to preg.](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6270004/converting-ereg-expressions-to-preg)

Comment: In my case the stock symbols are capital letters only.

Comment: $s_optionPattern = "/^[a-z0-9]{1,6}\s+(?:c|call|p|put)\s+[0-9\.]+\s+[0-9]{4}[0-9]{2}[0-9]{2}$/i";

$s_symbol = "TQNT CALL 6 20120519";
$s_symbol2 = "BRK'B CALL 80 20120317";
echo "<br>--->".preg_match($s_optionPattern, $s_symbol);
echo "<br>--->".preg_match($s_optionPattern, $s_symbol2);

Comment: There is an [edit link](http://stackoverflow.com/posts/9598944/edit) below your question. Purge comment, and move it there.

Comment: To be sure if it is correct, try it!

Comment: I have tried and that is working fine. But i want to know adding (') character to the patter is correct or not.

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
    $pattern='/[a-zA-Z.]+/';
    $s_symbol   ='TQNT';
    $s_symbol2  =   "BRK.B";
    preg_match_all($pattern,$s_symbol,$matches1);
    print_r($matches1[0]);
    preg_match_all($pattern,$s_symbol2,$matches2);
    print_r($matches2[0]);
```