# Regex: php match url

Tags: php, regex

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Converting ereg expressions to preg](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6270004/converting-ereg-expressions-to-preg)

`http://www.google.co.in/aclk?sa=`L&ai=C_jFQq_

`http://www.google.co.in/aclk?sa=`l&ai=CKKCUg

The highlighted part is common in my url.

My Regex

```
 if (preg_match('google.com/aclk\?sa\=L\&ai/i', $url))
```

Is this regex correct?
I want to match my regex to my url.

Comment: The string "that's not working" is not a built-in error message in PHP.  **Be more specific.**

Comment: "google.co.in" isn't "google.com"

Answer (score 0):

You've forgotten the delimiters:

```
if (preg_match('#google.com/aclk\?sa\=L\&ai/i#', $url))
                ^--                          ^--
```

Traditionally they're `/`, but since you're working on a URL, this is a case where it makes sense to use a different character, and I've chose `#` in this case.

It's unclear if that last `/i` is an actual delimiter and the case-insensitve flag, so I've left that in place as part of the pattern.

Answer (score 0):

Delimiter must not be alphanumeric or backslash, that is your error.