# could someone help me with my ereg_replace converted to preg_replace

Tags: preg-replace, ereg-replace

I just need a bit of help with my ereg_replace changed to preg_replace..

```
ereg_replace('<caption.*</caption>', '', $match);
```

and I've tried

```
preg_replace('/<caption.*</caption>/', '', $match);
```

but it doesn't work.. and it says "Warning: preg_replace(): Unknown modifier 'c'"

I'm new to this kinda thing.. so any help would be appreciated :)

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How can I convert ereg expressions to preg in PHP?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6270004/how-can-i-convert-ereg-expressions-to-preg-in-php)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `'c'` in question is the one in `</caption>` in your original regex. When the parser sees the `/`, it assumes that it's an ending delimiter, the regex is over, and it's looking for modifier flags. Not recognizing a modifier flag called `c` it throws the error you're seeing.

So you could fix things by escaping the slashes. In my mind, though, it might be more convenient to use a non-slash character (I'm partial to `#`) as your delimiter:

```
preg_replace('#<caption.*</caption>#', '', $match);
```

Comment: Thanks so much, that worked.. See now I didn't even know you could use # lol not so good with regexp :(

Comment: PHP's actually pretty open-minded about the delimiter...definitely a source of unnecessary confusion at times :^)