# Updating from ereg to preg_match

Tags: preg-match, ereg

I read similar titles but I couldn't make it run..

Now, I have a code like this (originally ereg):

```
        if (preg_match("[^0-9]",$qrcode_data_string)){
        if (preg_match("[^0-9A-Z \$\*\%\+\-\.\/\:]",$qrcode_data_string)) {
```

I also tried using / at the beginning and end of rule but didn't work.

Any replies welcome.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How can I convert ereg expressions to preg in PHP?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6270004/how-can-i-convert-ereg-expressions-to-preg-in-php)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

With the `preg_*` functions you need [delimiters](http://php.net/manual/en/regexp.reference.delimiters.php) around the pattern:

```
if (preg_match("#[^0-9]#", $qrcode_data_string)) {
#               ^      ^
```

From the documentation:

> When using the PCRE functions, it is required that the pattern is enclosed by delimiters. A delimiter can be any non-alphanumeric, non-backslash, non-whitespace character.
>
> Often used delimiters are forward slashes (/), hash signs (#) and tildes (~).

Comment: Thank you but, as I told, I already tried that.

If I use it for the first line only, it creates lot's of indexed which are invalid,

If I use it for both, I get
Message: QRcode : Overflow error

But if I use ereg, I only see notices, but the code works.

Comment: @erdemkeren: The delimiters are **required**, as you can see by reading the documentation. It's not a case of "I'll try it, but if it doesn't work then I'll remove them". You absolutely **do** need them. The other error is something else.

Comment: I see and understand that they are required. I read lot's of pages before asking this question here. I wanted to know if there is any other point that I miss.

You say the code is true but the script is false right?

Comment: @erdemkeren: That is the only thing I can see wrong with the code you posted. See your code working online: http://ideone.com/nSOLn. There may be other errors in other parts of your code that you haven't posted.

Comment: @erdemkeren: No I didn't miss it, but the problem with that line is *exactly* the same as with the first line: you need delimiters. Hopefully  you can fix the second line yourself?