# Replace eregi_replace preg_replace

Tags: php, preg-replace

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Converting ereg expressions to preg](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6270004/converting-ereg-expressions-to-preg)

How do I convert this function with this parameters

eregi_replace("[][,.?&\"#{(_\\@)\=+\,\?.;/:!%*()|}]+", "", $data);

to preg_replace?

Answer (score 0):

Your answer:
    preg_replace('/[][,.?&\"#{(_\@)\=+\,\?.;/:!%*()|}]+/', "", $data)

And please, [pre_replace](http://php.net/preg_replace) for more simples questions, in these places not everyone is as benevolent as me, probably you would have no answer, search before asking for asking