# having difficulties parsing the .cfg file with php

Tags: php, file, parsing, config

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Converting ereg expressions to preg](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6270004/converting-ereg-expressions-to-preg)

I am totally new to parsing a cfg file to php. Still tried to search couple of website and i found this exmaple. But it has some errors in it. I dont understand how can i solve them.

I have a .cfg file named `my_config.cfg`. It has the information as shown below.

```
# ATA/IDE/MFM/RLL support
#
CONFIG_IDE=y

#
# IDE, ATA and ATAPI Block devices
#
CONFIG_BLK_DEV_IDE=y
CONFIG_BLK_DEV_IDEDISK=y
CONFIG_BLK_DEV_IDECD=n
```

I am trying to parse it in php.

Code:

```
<?php
$config_file = "my_config.cfg";
$comment = "#";

$fp = fopen($config_file, "r");

while (!feof($fp)) {
$line = trim(fgets($fp));
if ($line && !ereg("^$comment", $line)) {
$pieces = explode("=", $line);
$option = trim($pieces[0]);
$value = trim($pieces[1]);
$config_values[$option] = $value;
}
}
fclose($fp);

if ($config_values['CONFIG_IDE'] == "y")
echo "CONFIG_IDE is set&lt;br /&gt;";
else
echo "CONFIG_IDE is not set&lt;br /&gt;";
?>
```

But I am getting error:

```
Deprecated: Function ereg() is deprecated in C:\xampp\htdocs\test.php on line 9
CONFIG_IDE is set<br />
```

Any Solutions???

Comment: What's to ask? the ereg functions are deprecated, and you shouldn't be using them.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

That deprecation warning indicates you should find a different function to perform what you need.  More info on [PHP's ereg documentation page](https://www.php.net/ereg).  How about [preg_match()](http://us.php.net/preg_match) instead?

```
if ($line && !preg_match("/^$comment/", $line)) {
    ...
}
```

But instead of using a regular expression, you might be able to get away with using `substr()`, like this:

```
if ($line && substr($line, 0, 1) != $comment) {
    ...
}
```

Firing up the regex matching subsystem on each iteration of your loop is expensive, performance-wise.  `substr()` is way cheaper!

By the way, what about using `parse_ini_file()` here?  In my tests of your code and your sample Linux kernel config snippet, it produces the same thing, but with 1 line of code instead of 12.

Comment: I tried `preg_match` but still some error : `Warning: preg_match() [function.preg-match]: No ending delimiter '^' found in C:\xampp\htdocs\test.php on line 9

Notice: Undefined offset: 1 in C:\xampp\htdocs\test.php on line 12`

Comment: Oopse, I forgot the delimiters.  I fixed my answer.  Should work now.  Good luck!

Comment: Thanks `curtisdf` and `sachleen` for your help...it worked...

Comment: hey one more question...i was able to do this successfully because my config file was in the same folder with my php. But what if i want to use the config file remotely? Any idea?

Comment: You can still make it work with a remote config file.  `fopen()` works if you give it a full URL.

Answer (score 1):

You have `&amp;&amp;`... that should be `&&`

```
if ($line && !ereg("^$comment", $line)) {
```

As of PHP 5.3.0, [`ereg`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.ereg.php) has been deprecated. You should be using [`preg_match`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.preg-match.php) instead. The syntax will be the same for you.

Comment: i tried that but i am getting this error. `Deprecated: Function ereg() is deprecated in C:\xampp\htdocs\test.php on line 9

Deprecated: Function ereg() is deprecated in C:\xampp\htdocs\test.php on line 9

Deprecated: Function ereg() is deprecated in C:\xampp\htdocs\test.php on line 9

Deprecated: Function ereg() is deprecated in C:\xampp\htdocs\test.php on line 9

Deprecated: Function ereg() is deprecated in C:\xampp\htdocs\test.php on line 9

Deprecated: Function ereg() is deprecated in C:\xampp\htdocs\test.php on line 9
CONFIG_IDE is set<br />`

Comment: Use `preg_match` instead. See updated answer.

Comment: Ok. I'll try it with preg_match...Thanks `sachleen`