# preg_replace: how to?

Tags: php, regex, preg-replace

If there is one thing I can't understand ( or learn ), then that's `preg_replace` syntax. I need help removing all possible symbols ( space, tab, new line, etc. ) between `>` and `<`.

Meaning, I have such XML:

```
<?xml version=\"1.0\" encoding=\"UTF-8\"?><bl>  <snd>BANK</snd>    <rcv>ME</rcv>  <intid>773264</intid> <date>17072012</date></bl>
```

I need it to look:

```
<?xml version=\"1.0\" encoding=\"UTF-8\"?><bl><snd>BANK</snd><rcv>ME</rcv><intid>773264</intid><date>17072012</date></bl>
```

So far I came up with this:

```
$this -> data = preg_replace('\>(.*?)<\', '><', $data);
```

But it doesn't even come close to what I need. A solution would be appreciated.

Comment: possible duplicate of [converting ereg to preg (missing regex delimiters)](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6270004/converting-ereg-expressions-to-preg)

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You're close, you just need delimiters and to restrict your search for space characters:

```
preg_replace('#>\s+<#', '><', $data);
```

Where `#` is the delimiter character, and `\s` is shorthand for any space characters.

You can see it working in [this example](http://viper-7.com/gfNT8O).

Comment: Will it also remove possible tab symbols? I updated the question. There should be only spaces, but who knows.

Answer (score 1):

For removing spaces:

```
preg_replace('/\s\s+/', ' ', $data);
```

For removing new lines:

```
$string = preg_replace('/\r\n/', "", $data);
```