# Regex correct in PCRE

Tags: php, regex, pcre

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Converting ereg expressions to preg](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6270004/converting-ereg-expressions-to-preg)

I have used this regex in php < v5.3.0

```
ereg('^http://www.w3.org/[0-9]{4}/XMLSchema$',$value)
```

As I updated to php v.5.3.0 I am trying to use preg_match(), but I have hard time creating PCRE regex which is equivalent:

```
preg_match('/^http\\:\\/\\/www\\.w3\\.org\\/[0-9]{4}\\/XMLSchema$/',$value)
```

Could someone help on this one?

Comment: Try `preg_match('#^http://www\.w3\.org/[0-9]{4}/XMLSchema$#', $value)`. You can use other non-alphanumerics as the regexp delimiter, not just `/`, and that usually results in more readable expressions.

Comment: Hi, thanks for quickness - actually this worked: preg_match('/^http://www\.w3\.org/[0-9]{4}/XMLSchema$/', $value).

Does it matter if it starts with # or /?

Comment: @ZeC: No, it doesn't matter; you can use any symbol

Answer (score 2):

You can you the same expression as in `ereg`:

```
preg_match('@^http://www[.]w3[.]org/[0-9]{4}/XMLSchema$@',$value)
```

Just take `@` instead of `/` as a delimiter.
And don't forget to escape dots (`.` means "any symbol" in a regular expression). You can do this using backslashes but I prefer symbol class `[.]` for that.

Comment: I would think you have to escape the dots though, as a dot matches everything?