# PHP Function ereg_replace() is deprecated

Tags: php, mysql

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Converting ereg expressions to preg](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6270004/converting-ereg-expressions-to-preg)

I have this Function For filter wrod (bad word) form title/desc. now i see `ereg_replace() is deprecated` php error `Deprecated: Function ereg_replace() is deprecated in C:\xampp\htdocs\share\configs\functions.php on line 2750` and this `Warning: Cannot modify header information - headers already sent by (output started at C:\xampp\htdocs\share\configs\functions.php:2747) in C:\xampp\htdocs\share\modules\signup\signup.php on line 31` in my page. what's problem? how to fix this ?

This is My Function :

```
    function filter_title($str)
{
    global $config;

    if ( $config['word_filters'] == '1' ) { $str = filterBadWords ( $str ); }
    if ( $config['word_filters'] == '0' ) { $str=mysql_real_escape_string($str); }
    //if ( $config['word_filters'] == '1' ) { $str = filterBadWords ( urlencode($str) ); }

    //$newstr=str_replace('"',"'",$str);
    $pats1 ='\'';  $repls1 ="";
    $pat[] ='\"';  $repl[] ="";
    $pat[] ='\&';  $repl[] =" and ";
    $pat[] ='\~';  $repl[] ="";
    $pat[] ='\@';  $repl[] ="";
    $pat[] ='\#';  $repl[] ="";
    $pat[] ='\$';  $repl[] ="";
    $pat[] ='\%';  $repl[] ="";
    $pat[] ='\^';  $repl[] ="";
    $pat[]='\*';  $repl[]="";
    $pat[]='\(';  $repl[]="";
    $pat[]='\)';  $repl[]="";
    $pat[]='\+';  $repl[]=" ";
    $pat[]='\`';  $repl[]="";
    $pat[]='\=';  $repl[]="";
    $pat[]='\!';  $repl[]="";
    $pat[]='\[';  $repl[]="";
    $pat[]='\]';  $repl[]="";
    $pat[]='\{';  $repl[]="";
    $pat[]='\}';  $repl[]="";
    $pat[]='\;';  $repl[]="";
    $pat[]='\:';  $repl[]="";
    $pat[]='\.';  $repl[]="";
    $pat[]='\/';  $repl[]="";
    $pat[]='\?';  $repl[]="";
    $pat[]='\<';  $repl[]="";
    $pat[]='\>';  $repl[]="";
    //$pat[]='\_';  $repl[]=" ";
    $pat[]="\\\\"; $repl[]="";
    $pat[]='\|';  $repl[]="";
    $pat[]='\,';  $repl[]="";
    $pat[]='\0x';  $repl[]="";

    $newstr = ereg_replace($pats1, $repls1, $str);    // ---> 2747 <---     
    for($i=0;$pat[$i];$i++) {
    $newstr = ereg_replace($pat[$i], $repl[$i], $newstr); // ---> 2750 <---
    }

    $newstr = preg_replace('/\s\s+/', ' ', $newstr); 

    return trim ( $newstr );
}
```

This My filter_descr function :

```
function filter_descr($str)
    {
        //$str=mysql_real_escape_string($str);
        global $config;

        if ( $config['word_filters'] == '1' ) { $str = filterBadWords ( $str ); }
        if ( $config['word_filters'] == '0' ) { $str = mysql_real_escape_string($str); }
        //if ( $config['word_filters'] == '1' ) { $str = filterBadWords ( urlencode ( $str ) ); }

        //$newstr=str_replace('"',"'",$str);
        $pats1 = "\'";  $repls1 ="&#39;";
        $pat[] = '\"';  $repl[] ="&#34;";
        $pat[] = '\&';  $repl[] ="&amp;";
        //$pat[] ='\~';  $repl[] ="";
        //$pat[] ='\@';  $repl[] ="";
        //$pat[] ='\#';  $repl[] ="";
        $pat[] = '\$';  $repl[] ="";
        $pat[] = '\%';  $repl[] ="";
        $pat[] = '\{';  $repl[] ="";
        $pat[] = '\}';  $repl[]="";
        $pat[] = '\`';  $repl[]="";
        //$pat[]='\/';  $repl[]="";
        $pat[] = '\<';  $repl[]="";
        $pat[] = '\>';  $repl[]="";
        //$pat[]="\\\\"; $repl[]="";
        $pat[] = '\|';  $repl[]="";
        //$pat[]="\n";  $repl[]="<br>";
        //$pat[]='\r';  $repl[]="<br>";
        $pat[] = '\0x';  $repl[]="";

        $newstr = ereg_replace($pats1, $repls1, $str);

        for($i=0;$pat[$i];$i++) {
        $newstr=ereg_replace($pat[$i], $repl[$i], $newstr);
        }

        $newstr = preg_replace('/\s\s+/', ' ', $newstr);

        return trim ( $newstr );
    }
```

PHP Signup ( LINE 31 commented ) :

```
session_start();
include('../../configs/config.php');

$smarty->assign('country', set_country_box(filter_title($_REQUEST['fcountry'])));
//if somebody is logged in and active, we don't need to see the registration page
if ($_SESSION["USERNAME"]!="" && $_SESSION["IS_ACTIVE"]=="1")
{
    header("Location: $config[base_url]/main");
    exit;
}

//if Cancel is pressed
if (filter_descr($_REQUEST[scancel])!="")
{
    header("Location: $config[base_url]/main"); // ----> LINE 31 <----
    exit;
}
```

Comment: Give him a change, His question title is only wrong.

Comment: What's so hard to understand about "deprecated"? http://php.net/manual/en/function.ereg-replace.php   5 seconds of reading on the OFFICIAL documentation site would've answered this for you.

Comment: He is getting `header()` function error too.

Answer (score 4):

Don't use `ereg_replace()` as it is deprecated. Use [`preg_replace()`](http://php.net/preg_replace). From a quick glance at your function, you *should* be able to simply convert the functions.

As far as the *headers already sent* error. This is likely due to the *deprecated warning message* being output before you call `header()`.

Although correcting the above should solve the problem. If this is production, you should strongly consider disabling [display_errors](http://www.php.net/manual/en/errorfunc.configuration.php#ini.display-errors).

Answer (score 0):

When ever you use header function , then if even a single space is sent as response before you send actual output you will get error

```
Warning: Cannot modify header information - headers already sent by (output started at C:\xampp\htdocs\share\configs\functions.php:2747)
```

it is good not to close php ending tag. Check have you and white space and for other errors @Json Has given the answer use `preg_replace()` instead.