# What does this PHP regular expression mean?

Tags: php, regex, ereg

I'm learning PHP regular expressions, and I came across something I'm having trouble making sense of.

The book gives this example in validating an e-mail address.

```
if (ereg("^[^@]+@([a-z0-9\-]+\.)+[a-z]{2,4}$", $email))
```

I'm not clear on a couple elements of this expression.

1. what does this mean `[^@]+@`
2. What is the purpose of the parentheses in `([a-z0-9\-]+\.)`?

Comment: Try this tutorial:  http://www.regular-expressions.info/tutorial.html/

Comment: don't use ereg, its depreciated, i would say you book is dated. Don't use regular expressions for validating email addresses; use filters

Answer (score 6):

`[^@]+@` means:

```
[   - Match this group of characters
 ^@ - Anything that is NOT an at sign
]
+   - One or more times
@   - Match an at sign
```

So, it's essentially matching every character before the first at sign.

The purpose of parenthesis in `([a-z0-9-]+.)` is to create a [capturing group](http://www.regular-expressions.info/brackets.html), which you should be able to reference later on once the group captures some amount of text.

Also note that `ereg_*` functions are deprecated, and your book must be a bit dated. Nowadays, we use the `preg_*` family of functions. A tutorial on converting them can be found in [this SO question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6270004/converting-ereg-expressions-to-preg).

Comment: fyi that's not an [ampersand](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ampersand), it's an [at sign](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/At_sign).

Comment: Thanks, and yeah I noticed the tutorials are written in POSIX syntax, which brings up deprecated errors like you said. I use PCRE which is more up to date.