# preg_match() error

Tags: php

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Converting ereg expressions to preg](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6270004/converting-ereg-expressions-to-preg)

I downloaded the Ocomon and edit the languages ​​appeared: **Deprecated: Function ereg() is deprecated**. So, I researched and talked about what I should change for preg_match (), but gave the following error: **Delimiter must not be alphanumeric or backslash**.

The code is this:

```
ereg("^[0-9a-z]([-_.]?[0-9a-z])*@[0-9a-z]([-.]?[0-9a-z])*\\.[a-z]{2,3}$",$email)
```

Comment: `filter_var('bob@example.com', FILTER_VALIDATE_EMAIL)`

Answer (score 1):

You need delimiters around your regular expression. Forward slashes are typical:

```
"/^[0-9a..........{2,3}$/"
```

As it stands, the regular expression engine things you're tying to use `^` as your opening delimiter, which is not allowed.

Comment: But you will want to make sure that you escape `/` as `\/` (if there are any) inside the regexp or you will experience even weirder errors. ;-)