# PHP regex to extract first part of file name in URL

Tags: php, regex, extract, filenames

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [How can I convert ereg expressions to preg in PHP?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6270004/how-can-i-convert-ereg-expressions-to-preg-in-php)

I'm working on a PHP script.

I have a URL of the form:

http://ecx.images-amazon.com/images/I/5104Xl51zFL._SL175_.jpg

and I simply want to grab the first part of the file name `5104Xl51zFL`.

I'm pretty new to regexps but so far I have:

```
.*images\/I\/(.+?)(\.[^.]*|$)
```

which according to regextester.com should work but doesn't in my PHP.

Doesn't have to be a regexp if it's not the best solution.

If it's relevant here's my PHP (still debuggy):

```
function linkExtractor($html)
{
    if(preg_match_all('/<img ([^>]* )?src=[\"\']([^\"\']*\._SL175_\.jpe?g)[\"\']/Ui', $html, $matches, PREG_SET_ORDER)){
        foreach ($matches as $match) {
            $url = $match[2];
            echo "\n\n" .$url . "\nfile name: ";
            if(preg_match_all('.*images\/I\/(.+?)(\.[^.]*|$)', $url, $matched, PREG_SET_ORDER)) {
                foreach($matched as $name) {
                    print_r($matched);
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 8, accepted):

```
$url = 'http://ecx.images-amazon.com/images/I/5104Xl51zFL._SL175_.jpg';
$path = parse_url($url, PHP_URL_PATH);
$filename = basename($path);
$partOne = strtok($filename, '.');
```

Comment: perfect - was looking for a way to do this without regexps anyway

Comment: wouldn't that give you "com/images/I/5104Xl51zFL" not "5104Xl51zFL"?

Comment: Oh I see how I was wrong now.

Answer (score 1):

This will match everything between `/images/I/` and `.`

```
$url = 'http://ecx.images-amazon.com/images/I/5104Xl51zFL._SL175_.jpg';
if(preg_match('~/images/I/(.+?)\.~',$url,$match)) {
    $name = $match[1];
}
```

Answer (score 1):

One way using `regex`:

```
$str='http://ecx.images-amazon.com/images/I/5104Xl51zFL._SL175_.jpg';
preg_match('/.*\/(.*?)\./',$str,$match);
print $match[1];

>>> 5104Xl51zFL
```

Explanation:

```
.*    # Match anything
\/    # Up to the last forwardslash (escaped)
(.*?) # Match anything after (captured, lazy)
\.    # Up to the first . (escaped)
```

Answer (score 1):

If you're still looking for a regular expression to extract that part of the filename here is one:

```
([^/.]++)[^/]+$
```

This expression will match the full filename. Capture group 1 will contain every character in the filename that is before the first dot.

The ++ makes this regex faster than with only one +. This is because when a piece of text fails to match, the regex will fail more quickly.

Answer (score 0):

```
$file = basename("http://ecx.images-amazon.com/images/I/5104Xl51zFL._SL175_.jpg");
echo substr($file, 0, strpos($file, "."));
```

`strpos` is much faster than using regular expressions for something that simple