# Deprecated: Function ereg() is deprecated

Tags: php, forms, deprecated, eregi, ereg

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [How can I convert ereg expressions to preg in PHP?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6270004/how-can-i-convert-ereg-expressions-to-preg-in-php)

My contact form is othervise working but I keep getting the following 
error:

> Deprecated: Function ereg() is deprecated in/home/.....

I'm really lost here but I figure this is the part that needs some adjusting.

```
    if ( empty($_REQUEST['name']) ) {
    $pass = 1;
    $alert .= $emptyname;
} elseif ( ereg( "[][{}()*+?.\\^$|]", $_REQUEST['name'] ) ) {    
    $pass = 1;
    $alert .= $alertname;
}
if ( empty($_REQUEST['email']) ) {
    $pass = 1;
    $alert .= $emptyemail;
} elseif ( !eregi("^[_a-z0-9-]+(.[_a-z0-9-]+)*@[a-z0-9-]+(.[a-z0-9-]+)*(.[a-z]   {2,3})$", $_REQUEST['email']) ) {
    $pass = 1;
    $alert .= $alertemail;
}
if ( empty($_REQUEST['message']) ) {
    $pass = 1;
    $alert .= $emptymessage;
} elseif ( preg_match( "[][{}()*+?\\^$|]", $_REQUEST['message'] ) ) {
    $pass = 1;
    $alert .= $alertmessage;
}
```

Finding a solution would be highly appreciated

Comment: You're not the owner of http://computertrouble.com/ by any chance are you? Just curious.

Answer (score 42, accepted):

You must use [`preg_match`](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.preg-match.php) instead of [`ereg`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.ereg.php) because the last one is deprecated.

Replacing it is not a big deal:

```
ereg( "[][{}()*+?.\\^$|]", $_REQUEST['name'] )
```

will become:

```
preg_match( "/[][{}()*+?.\\^$|]/", $_REQUEST['name'] )
```

p.s. I had to modify more than one hundred files while I was porting my old project to PHP 5.3 to avoid manually modifying I've used following script to do it for me:

```
function replaceEregWithPregMatch($path) {
    $content = file_get_contents($path);
    $content = preg_replace('/ereg\(("|\')(.+)(\"|\'),/',
                            "preg_match('/$2/',",
                            $content);
    file_put_contents($path, $content);
}
```

I hope it helps.

Comment: Note that there are [delimeters](http://php.net/manual/en/regexp.reference.delimiters.php) in `preg_match`.

Answer (score 3):

The function `ereg()` is deprecated and should not be used any more. The [documentation](http://php.net/manual/en/function.ereg.php) tells you what to do (to use `preg_match` instead).

Answer (score 0):

Like you said - no bigie, it works like a charm:

```
if ( empty($_REQUEST['name']) ) {
    $pass = 1;
    $alert .= $emptyname;
} elseif ( preg_match( "/[][{}()*+?.\\^$|]/", $_REQUEST['name'] ) ) {  
    $pass = 1;
    $alert .= $alertname;
}
if ( empty($_REQUEST['email']) ) {
    $pass = 1;
    $alert .= $emptyemail;
} elseif ( !preg_match("#^[_a-z0-9-]+(\.[_a-z0-9-]+)*@[a-z0-9-]+(\.[a-z0-9-]+)*(\.[a-z]{2,3})$#i", $_REQUEST['email']) ) {
    $pass = 1;
    $alert .= $alertemail;
}
if ( empty($_REQUEST['message']) ) {
    $pass = 1;
    $alert .= $emptymessage;
} elseif ( preg_match( "/[][{}()*+?\\^$|]/", $_REQUEST['message'] ) ) {
    $pass = 1;
    $alert .= $alertmessage;
}
```

Thank you guys