# 500 error in PHP code

Tags: php

I'm trying to make a login page for a website that I'm working on, I have access to the server.

I can load some pages that work 100%, but when I go to add a member to the site, it gives me an error message saying:

> **Error 500**
>
> The sharedweb.unisite.ac.uk page isn’t working. sharedweb.unisite.ac.uk is currently unable to handle this request.

and I don't know why. The script that's causing this error is:

```
<?php

  // include function files for this application
  require_once('bookmark_fns.php');

  //create short variable names
  $email=$_POST['email'];
  $username=$_POST['username'];
  $passwd=$_POST['passwd'];
  $passwd2=$_POST['passwd2'];
  // start session which may be needed later
  // start it now because it must go before headers
  session_start();
  try   {
    // check forms filled in
    if (!filled_out($_POST)) {
      throw new Exception('You have not filled the form out correctly. Please go back and try again.');
    }

    // email address not valid
    if (!valid_email($email)) {
      throw new Exception('That is not a valid email address.  Please go back and try again.');
    }

    // passwords not the same
    if ($passwd != $passwd2) {
      throw new Exception('The passwords you entered do not match. Please go back and try again.');
    }

    // check password length is ok
    // ok if username truncates, but passwords will get
    // munged if they are too long.
    if (!preg_match('/^(?=.*\d)(?=.*[A-Za-z])[0-9A-Za-z]{6,12}$/)', $passwd)) {
        throw new Exception('Your password must be between 6 and 12 characters inclusive. Please go back and try again.');
    }

    // attempt to register
    // this function can also throw an exception
    register($username, $email, $passwd);
    // register session variable
    $_SESSION['valid_user'] = $username;

    // provide link to members page
    do_html_header('Registration successful');
    echo "Welcome " $_POST["username"];
    echo 'Your registration was successful.  Go to the members page to start setting up your bookmarks!';
    do_html_url('member.php', 'Go to members page');

   // end page
   do_html_footer();
  }
  catch (Exception $e) {
     do_html_header('Warning:');
     echo $e->getMessage();
     do_html_footer();
     exit;
  }
?>
```

How can I fix this?

Comment: set error reporting on

Comment: this has a syntax error for one thing `echo "Welcome " $_POST["username"];` no concatenation and no idea if the session was started.

Comment: @JainilNagar I have done and it's not showing anything, only the `error 500` problem

Comment: You shouldn't print a value received from the client (via $_POST here). Sanitize it first

Comment: Using a good code editor would have avoided this question altogether, not to mention error checking.

Comment: Please see the answer below.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There's 2 syntax errors in your code:

Firstly, you need to concat string with a variable using `.`:

```
echo "Welcome " . $_POST["username"];
```

Secondly, there's an extra closing bracket here:

```
if (!preg_match('/^(?=.*\d)(?=.*[A-Za-z])[0-9A-Za-z]{6,12}$/)', $passwd)) {
    throw new Exception('Your password must be between 6 and 12 characters inclusive. Please go back and try again.');
}
```

Remove the extra bracket:

```
if (!preg_match('/^(?=.*\d)(?=.*[A-Za-z])[0-9A-Za-z]{8,12}$/', $passwd)) {
    throw new Exception('Your password must be between 6 and 12 characters inclusive. Please go back and try again.');
}
```

---

As for this error:

> Deprecated: Function ereg() is deprecated

PHP Manual:

> [`ereg()`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.ereg.php) was DEPRECATED in PHP 5.3.0, and REMOVED in PHP 7.0.0.

Check out this post: [Deprecated: Function ereg() is deprecated](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13580784/deprecated-function-ereg-is-deprecated)

---

**Tip:** You should turn on [**Error Reporting**](http://php.net/manual/en/function.error-reporting.php) by adding this code to the top of your PHP files which will assist you in finding errors.

```
<?php 
error_reporting(E_ALL);
ini_set('display_errors', 1);
```

Comment: Thanks for the help! I've managed to get a page displayed now. However now, with the error reporting turned on, I have `Undefined index` for the email on line 8, username on line 9, password on line 10, and password2 on line 11 and Function ereg() is deprecated on line 15

Comment: @johnsmith This means that there's something wrong with the form that values are not submitted, maybe also post your form code?

Comment: I went back and resubmitted the form, and I have got `Deprecated: Function ereg() is deprecated` on line 15 and `Warning: preg_match(): Unknown modifier ')'` on line 34 but when I take that out, I get the `error 500` message again

Comment: @johnsmith I've updated post to fix the `preg_match()` error

Comment: @johnsmith You're welcome! Maybe accept this post by clicking on the tick mark below the upvote/ downvote buttons if it helped you, thanks :)