# PHP: deprecated EREG_REPLACE to PREG_REPLACE

Tags: php, preg-replace, ereg-replace

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [How can I convert ereg expressions to preg in PHP?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6270004/how-can-i-convert-ereg-expressions-to-preg-in-php)

What is the equivalent of this EREG_REPLACE function in PREG_REPLACE?

```
$html = ereg_replace("[^A-Za-z._0-9@ ]"," ",$html);
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
$html = preg_replace("/[^A-Za-z._0-9@ ]/"," ",$html);
```

The biggest difference is the delimiters on the ends, though there are others. Read [here](http://docstore.mik.ua/orelly/webprog/pcook/ch13_02.htm).

Answer (score 0):

`$html = preg_replace("/[^A-Za-z._0-9@ ]/"," ",$html);`

[preg_replace](http://php.net/manual/en/function.preg-replace.php)