# what reg expression would select all the text between these tags?

Tags: php, regex

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [RegEx match open tags except XHTML self-contained tags](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1732348/regex-match-open-tags-except-xhtml-self-contained-tags)
>   [How to parse and process HTML with PHP?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3577641/how-to-parse-and-process-html-with-php)
>   [How can I convert ereg expressions to preg in PHP?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6270004/how-can-i-convert-ereg-expressions-to-preg-in-php)

here is an example

```
echo "<div id='spaced' class='romaji'><span class='spaced orig word'>neko</span><span class='space'>";
```

please ignore the "echos" its the only way i could get the html to show

i need a reg express that can select whatever is between the

```
echo "<span class='spaced orig word'>";
```

tag and its ending tag

```
echo "</span>";
```

i tried

```
$pattern = "span class='spaced orig word'>(.+?)</s";
preg_match_all ($pattern, $jp_page, $result_ro);
if ($result_ro[1])
$results[] = implode(' ', $result_ro[1]);
else
return null; // Failed to retrieve Hiragana, so abort
```

and some other things, but i cant get it right, i get nothing most of the time because i dont really know what im doing with reg expressions

currently getting a warning with this code
Warning: preg_match_all(): Delimiter must not be alphanumeric or backslash

Comment: When you have to selet a few things you may consider to use a HTML parser instead of parsing the HTML with regular expressions.

Comment: Specific to your error: *Where **ARE** your delimiters?* - Your pattern needs a forwardslash, hash, tidle, or something at either end.

Answer (score 1):

[THE PONY HE COMES!](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1732348/regex-match-open-tags-except-xhtml-self-contained-tags/1732454#1732454)

Instead, try using a DOM parser:

```
$dom = new DOMDocument();
$dom->loadHTML($jp_page);
$xpath = new DOMXPath($dom);
$spans = $xpath->query("//span[@class='spaced orig word']");
$results = "";
foreach($spans as $span) {
    $results = " ".$span->textContent;
}
$results = trim($results);
return $results;
```

Comment: You know I always read that as "Zalgo is Tony the Pony, he comes"

Answer (score -2):

No delimiters
try this reg

```
<?php
$pattern = '@<span.*?>(.*?)</span>@';
```