# Deprecated: Function eregi() is deprecated contact form

Tags: php

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [How can I convert ereg expressions to preg in PHP?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6270004/how-can-i-convert-ereg-expressions-to-preg-in-php)

I have a php contact form that I have used on a few different websites. I am trying to implement the same one on a new site, but I am getting the following message:

Deprecated: Function eregi() is deprecated in /home/content/58/10223058/html/contact-1.php on line 36

Here is line 36 from my code:

```
if(!eregi($string_exp,$name)) {
    $error_message .= 'The Name you entered does not appear to be valid.<br />';
  }
```

I am sure there is an easy fix for this, but I am very new to PHP and do not know how to go about fixing this!

Any help would be greatly appreciated. Thankyou

Comment: So the proper action in your case will be to convert the variable `$string_exp` to a PCRE expression and use `preg_match()` instead of `eregi()`.

Comment: eregi is deprecated in PHP 5.3. http://php.net/manual/en/function.eregi.php If your different websites upgrade to PHP 5.3+, you will have the same problem there.

Answer (score 4):

1) It's just a warning.  I'm guessing the code still works, despite the warning.  Correct?

2) You can fix it by Googling "Function eregi() is deprecated".  For example:

http://takien.com/513/how-to-fix-function-eregi-is-deprecated-in-php-5-3-0.php

```
// Old
if(!eregi("^[_\.0-9a-zA-Z-]+@([0-9a-zA-Z][0-9a-zA-Z-]+\.)+[a-zA-Z]{2,6}$", $str)) {
    $msg = 'email is not valid';
}
else {
    $valid = true;
}

// New
if(!preg_match("/^[_\.0-9a-zA-Z-]+@([0-9a-zA-Z][0-9a-zA-Z-]+\.)+[a-zA-Z]{2,6}$/i", $str)) {
    $msg = 'email is not valid';
}
else {
    $valid = true;
}
```

Complete PHP on-line documentation is here:

- http://php.net/manual/en/index.php

The "man page" for preg_match() is here:

- http://php.net/manual/en/function.preg-match.php

Comment: Wow, thats a quick reply, thankyou!

Comment: yes, the form still works

Comment: But the warning is very unsightly!

Comment: Fair enough.  To eliminate the warning, simply substitute "preg_match()".  Complete PHP documentation is on-line here: http://php.net/manual/en/index.php

Comment: > 2) You can fix it by Googling "Function eregi() is deprecated"

I just did - that's why I'm here!

Answer (score 3):

In most cases you can replace

```
if(!eregi($string_exp,$name)) {
```

with

```
if(!preg_match('/'.$string_exp.'/i',$name)) {
```

but not always - you have to check the pattern (`$string_exp`).

You could, however, just disable the message by putting this somewhere before the `eregi()` call:

```
error_reporting(error_reporting() & ~E_DEPRECATED);
```