# Deprecated: Function ereg() is deprecated in ...(Google cooridinates map)

Tags: php

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [How can I convert ereg expressions to preg in PHP?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6270004/how-can-i-convert-ereg-expressions-to-preg-in-php)

I am getting the above (subject) error from:

```
if (ereg('<coordinates>([0-9.-]{1,}),([0-9.-]{1,}).*</coordinates>', $result, $regs))
```

So I did this:

```
if (preg_match('<coordinates>/[0-9.-]{1,}\/,\/[0-9.-]{1,}/.*</coordinates>/', $result, $regs))
```

Now the Google map doesn't show up at all and it also warns "..cannot find coordinates..."

Where did I go wrong?

Thanks!

Comment: And you know, you could always use SimpleXML for reading... XML.

Answer (score 0):

You need [delimiters](http://php.net/manual/en/regexp.reference.delimiters.php) around your pattern when using PCRE functions:

```
if (preg_match('~<coordinates>/[0-9.-]{1,}\/,\/[0-9.-]{1,}/.*</coordinates>/~', $result, $regs))
```

Notice the `~` at the beginning and end.
Normally, people use `/` as a delimiter, but because it shows up so frequently in your pattern, an alternate delimiter has been selected.

As @nickb mentioned, have a look at this discussion:
[How can I convert ereg expressions to preg in PHP?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6270004/how-can-i-convert-ereg-expressions-to-preg-in-php)

Comment: Tried it. Now I am getting error: Unable to get map center coordinates, please verify your location! (249 Maitland...)