# PHP MySQL echo variables with a comma

Tags: php, mysql

how would I go about adding a comma after each echo'ed out variable but not after the last one?

At current I display the list like so:

```
    while ($row = mysqli_fetch_array($query3)) {
        $tag = $row['tag'];  
        $tagformat = eregi_replace("_", "&nbsp;", $tag);
$blogDisplay .= $tagformat.' ';
        }
```

This displays: testtag1 testtag2 testtag3

I would like it to display: testtag1, testtag2, testtag3

Any help would be great!

Edit for SQL Query:

```
$sqlCommand3 = "SELECT tag FROM blogtags WHERE blogid='$blogid'";
        $query3 = mysqli_query($myConnection, $sqlCommand3) or die (mysqli_error());
```

Also $blogDisplay has other values:

```
$blogDisplay .= '<h1><a href="/blog/'. $blogseourl .'"> ' . $blogtitle . ' </a></h1> ' . $contentshort . '... <a href="/blog/'. $blogseourl .'">Read More...</a><br /><br /> ' . $author . ' posted on ' . $blogtime . ' &#124;  Category: ' . $category . ' &#124;  Tags: ';
    while ($row = mysqli_fetch_array($query3)) {
        $tag = $row['tag'];  
        $tag = str_replace("_", "&nbsp;", $tag);
$blogDisplay .= $tag.' ';
        }
$blogDisplay .= ' &#124; <a href="/blog/'. $blogseourl .'#disqus_thread"></a>';
```

Comment: ereg functions are deprecated. Use `preg_replace()` in their stead. See [How can I convert ereg expressions to preg in PHP?](http://stackoverflow.com/q/6270004)

Comment: What's the query that you've used? You can do most of this inside MySQL itself if you're just iterating over tags.

Comment: Added the sql query and more information about $blogDisplay

Answer (score 2):

You could add them to an array, then [implode](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.implode.php) the array later:

```
$tags = array();
while ($row = mysqli_fetch_array($query3)) {
    $tag = $row['tag'];  
    $tagformat = eregi_replace("_", "&nbsp;", $tag);
    $tags[] = $tagformat;
}
echo implode(', ', $tags);
```

This separates the logic from the output, which wherever possible you should strive for. It'll make your life easier 6 months down the track when you come back to this code!

Answer (score 1):

```
$blogDisplay = "";
while ($row = mysqli_fetch_array($query3)) {
    $tag = $row['tag'];  
    $tagformat = eregi_replace("_", "&nbsp;", $tag);
    if ($blogDisplay!="") {
           $blogDisplay.=",";
     }
     if (trim($tagformat)!=""){
         $blogDisplay .= $tagformat;
     }
    }
```

Comment: This works but it also puts a comma at the beginning of the list :/

Comment: @Newcastlefan it shud not basically i have a if condition that checks if $blogDisplay !="" then only add a ","(comma)

Comment: I've used:
 while ($row = mysqli_fetch_array($query3)) {
  $tag = $row['tag'];  
  $tag = str_replace("_", "&nbsp;", $tag);
    if ($blogDisplay!='') {
           $blogDisplay.=", ";
     }
    if ($tag!=""){
         $blogDisplay .= $tag;
     }
    } 

But this displays as:

, testtag1, testtag2, testtag3

Comment: I think one of your $tag value is coming as whitespace?

Comment: I have added trim($tagformat) in if condition can you change and try again ?

Comment: $tag value has no whitespace values, and using the trim version still gives the same result.

Answer (score 1):

Try using **[implode](http://php.net/manual/en/function.implode.php)**.

```
$blogDisplay = array();
while ($row = mysqli_fetch_array($query3)) {
    $tag = $row['tag'];  
    $tagformat = eregi_replace("_", "&nbsp;", $tag); 
    $blogDisplay[] = $tagformat;
}

echo implode(', ', $blogDisplay);
```

Answer (score 1):

Your code needs some modifications only to achieve mentioned task,

```
while ($row = mysqli_fetch_array($query3)) {
    $tag = $row['tag'];  
    $tagformat = eregi_replace("_", "&nbsp;", $tag);
    $blogDisplay .= $tagformat.', '; //Here is the "," 
    }
```

Hope it helps.

Answer (score 1):

I don't see your echo, but I'm going to assume it's outside the while loop (please consider using a foreach loop instead).

Simply put the comma before the space in the eregi_replace.

```
while ($row = mysqli_fetch_array($query3)) {
    $tag = $row['tag'];  
    $tagformat = eregi_replace("_", ",&nbsp;", $tag);
    $blogDisplay .= $tagformat.' ';
}
```

Or:

```
while ($row = mysqli_fetch_array($query3)) {
    $tag = $row['tag'];  
    $tagformat = eregi_replace("_", "&#44;&nbsp;", $tag);
    $blogDisplay .= $tagformat.' ';
}
```

Or:

```
while ($row = mysqli_fetch_array($query3)) {
    $tag = $row['tag'];  
    $tagformat = eregi_replace("_", ", ", $tag);
    $blogDisplay .= $tagformat.' ';
}
```

Answer (score 0):

If you're only iterating over a set of tags from the database it would be easier to use this query:

```
SELECT GROUP_CONCAT(`tag` DELIMITER ', ') AS `tag`
FROM tags
WHERE ...
```

See also: [`GROUP_CONCAT()`](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/group-by-functions.html#function_group-concat)

The tags would already be nicely joined together by MySQL.

Also, don't use `eregi_replace`; in fact, don't use regular expressions:

```
str_replace('_', '&nbsp;', $tags);
```