# php eregi deprecated code confusion on the syntax

Tags: php

I am new to php, how do i change eregi from preg_match using this script:

```
if(!eregi("^select",$sql))
    {
        echo "wrongquery<br>$sql<p>";
        echo "<H2>Wrong function silly!</H2>\n";
        return false;
    }
```

is it like this:  if(!eregi("/^select/i",$sql))

thank you

Comment: if(!preg_match("%^select%i",$sql))

Comment: possible duplicate of [How can I convert ereg expressions to preg in PHP?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6270004/how-can-i-convert-ereg-expressions-to-preg-in-php)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use this:

```
if (!preg_match ("/^select/i", $sql))
{
    // do something...
}
```

Comment: You mean `"/^select/i"`?

Answer (score 2):

don't use regex for simple search of string, you can use one of the following:

```
$query = "select * from";
$keyword = "select";
if(strpos($query, "select") === 0){
 echo "found";
}
if(substr($query, 0, strlen("select")) === "select"){
 echo "found";
}
```