# Deprecated: Function ereg_replace() is deprecated

Tags: php

> Deprecated: Function ereg_replace() is deprecated in /home/hjlhvqyy/public_html/fastseoindia/klib/k_functions_text.php on line 114

The code is below:

```
$value = ereg_replace("[ ]{2,}"," ",$value); // line 114
```

Please, help me and give me a real code. I can't understand the full code, that's why I post my own question to get direct answer, because I can't make my own code to see the examples.

So, help me...

Comment: possible duplicate of [How can I convert ereg expressions to preg in PHP?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6270004/how-can-i-convert-ereg-expressions-to-preg-in-php)

Answer (score -1, accepted):

The function `ereg_replace()` is **deprecated**, that means that it is no longer supported by PHP by a particular reason (can be security or performance reasons, for example).

Instead, use `preg_replace()`. You also need to replace the regular expression string

```
[ ]{2,}
```

to

```
/[ ]{2,}/
```

[Read more about pattern delimiters.](http://php.net/manual/en/regexp.reference.delimiters.php)

Comment: thankz... to learn me this thing... i m thankful to you.....  you are a good teacher...

Comment: i want to give you a gift

Answer (score 3):

You need to use `preg_replace` because ereg_replace isn't supported anymore.

Comment: i tried it but after preg_replace it's not showing any report which its generate....

Answer (score 0):

I think it's

```
$value = preg_replace('/\s/' , ' ' , $value);
```