# Eregi function is deprecated

Tags: php, eregi

Here is my code (from submit.php) that is throwing an error:

```
$email_from = $_POST['email']; // required
$error_message = "";
$email_exp = "^[A-Z0-9._%-]+@[A-Z0-9.-]+\.[A-Z]{2,4}$";
if(!eregi($email_exp,$email_from)) {
$error_message .= 'The Email Address you entered does not appear to be valid.<br />';
}
```

I know I need to use preg_match, but I don't know how to implement it. I've read the documentation, but I still don't get it. Thanks!

Comment: Take a look at this question: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6270004/how-can-i-convert-ereg-expressions-to-preg-in-php

Comment: Perl regexps and POSIX regexps are very very similar to eachother. This one would work as a perl regexp automatically; no need to change anything within it. However, since you really want it to be case-INsensitive, you either have to add the i modifier at the end, or replace all A-Z with A-Za-z (ie. both cases).

Answer (score -1, accepted):

```
$email_exp = "/^[A-Z0-9._%-]+@[A-Z0-9.-]+\.[A-Z]{2,4}$/i";
 if(preg_match($email_exp,$email_from) != 1) {
    $error_message .= 'The Email Address you entered does not appear to be valid.<br />';
}
```

Actually, it'is very simple and very similar with eregi.

Answer (score -1):

remove this

```
  $email_exp = "^[A-Z0-9._%-]+@[A-Z0-9.-]+\.[A-Z]{2,4}$";
  eregi($email_exp,$email_from)
```

and use

```
$email_exp = "/^[A-Z0-9._%-]+@[A-Z0-9.-]+\.[A-Z]{2,4}$/i";
preg_match($email_exp, $email_from)
```

Comment: This is no longer case INsensitive. You're missing the i modifier

Comment: @Tularis its a typing mistake. i didnt notice it.Thanks for notifying.