# PHP ereg_replace is not working correctly

Tags: php, regex, ereg-replace

My id is `a5efa5`.

Code below replacing deprecated[?] `[^a-z0-9]` is not working. `a5efa5` in an id in my database table.

```
//Connect to the database through our include 
include_once "database.php";
// Get the member id from the URL variable
$id = $_REQUEST['id'];
$id = ereg_replace("[^a-z0-9]", "", $id); // filter everything but numbers for security
if (!$id) {
    echo "Missing Data to Run";
    exit(); 
}
```

Help me friends, where did I make a mistake...

Comment: "*It is not working*" is not useful. Please explain, if you get an error message (if so, which one) or if the results differ from your expectation (if so, how).

Comment: What is your question. What output are you expecting.. Can you provide an example

Comment: From your comment it seems that you want to avoid anything but numbers. Is this a case? Please explain what do you expect from that `a5efa5` id - is this valid or invalid?

Answer (score 1):

It could be because `ereg_replace` is [deprecated](https://www.php.net/function.ereg_replace).  Below is what is stated on the php.net website

> This function has been DEPRECATED as of PHP 5.3.0. Relying on this feature is highly discouraged.

If you are using a version or PHP greater than 5.3.0 then it will not work.

Comment: If feature is deprecated that does not mean that it will not work.

Comment: And there are much better questions/answers covering the deprecation of ereg_*: http://stackoverflow.com/q/6270004/46675

Answer (score 1):

Use preg_replace

```
$id = preg_replace('#[^a-z0-9]+#', '', $id);
```

Comment: its not accepting this a5efa5 id from table

Comment: Sorry, I have bug in my code, I update my post, see above

Comment: I agree that this is the right answer.