# Check text area for URLs with preg_match

Tags: preg-match, ereg

i found this code for checking a text area:

```
 if (strpos($textp, "http://") !== false ||
    ereg("(www.[a-zA-Z0-9_-]+)\.([a-zA-Z0-9.]+)",$textp)){
    $textp = '';
  } else {
```

because ereg is depreacted I would like to replacy by preg_match instead. But if I replace I got an error according to \
So what I should I exactly edit to get the same result - no URLs or elements of that inn that text area.

Comment: possible duplicate of [PHP: from ereg to preg\_match](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8007779/php-from-ereg-to-preg-match)

Comment: Your regex matches url like: `http://www.----.....`, I'm not sure it's valid!

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How can I convert ereg expressions to preg in PHP?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6270004/how-can-i-convert-ereg-expressions-to-preg-in-php)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you just need to add `/` like

```
  preg_match("/(www.[a-zA-Z0-9_-]+)\.([a-zA-Z0-9.]+)/",$textp)
```

please refer to [preg_match](http://pk1.php.net/preg_match)