# How to use ereg_replace to convert image link to display image

Tags: php, eregi, ereg, ereg-replace

How can i use ereg to replace URL of images with  tag.
My images URL have two starts embraced like this `**http://myimageslink/photo.jpg**` 
i want to convert to `<img src="http://myimageslink/photo.jpg"></img>`

I use ** embrace because when don't have ** `https://www.google.com/?gws_rd=ssl` i will convert to `<a href="https://www.google.com/?gws_rd=ssl">https://www.google.com/?gws_rd=ssl</a>` like this.

The code below doesn't work i got like this `<img src="**http://myimageslink/photo.jpg**"></img>`

```
   $text = ereg_replace("**[[:alpha:]]+://[^<>[:space:]]+[[:alnum:]/]**",
                             "<img src=\"\\0\"></img>", $str);
```

but I want the results like this.

```
<img src="http://myimageslink/photo.jpg"></img>
```

And this the real example.

```
$text  = 'This is first photo **http://myimageslink/photo.jpg**<br />
        This is second photo **http://myimageslink/photo.jpg**';
$text  = ereg_replace("**[[:alpha:]]+://[^<>[:space:]]+[[:alnum:]/]**",
                             "<img src=\"\\0\"></img>", $text);
```

So, $text  should be

```
$text = 'This is first photo <img src="http://myimageslink/photo.jpg"><br />
        This is second photo </img><img src="http://myimageslink/photo.jpg"></img>';
```

Comment: Sidenote: From the manual [`ereg_replace()`](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.ereg-replace.php) --- **Warning**
This function has been *DEPRECATED* as of PHP 5.3.0. Relying on this feature is highly discouraged. **Tip**
ereg_replace() is deprecated as of PHP 5.3.0. [`preg_replace()`](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.preg-replace.php) is the suggested alternative to this function.

Comment: As @Fred-ii- said `ereg_` has been deprecated for a long time now. Use `preg_` functions instead.

Comment: how can i use them for my question, suggest me for that, please,.

Comment: See SO's guide => http://stackoverflow.com/q/6270004/

Comment: Regardless of the advised switch, use capture groups, and not `\\0` to reinsert the whole match.