# ereg() to preg_match(), could you convert it for me?

Tags: php, preg-match, ereg

I am just becoming crazy and it seems not difficult...
Could please someone convert the following expression to the new function preg_match?

`ereg( "([0-9]{1,2})([0-9]{1,2})([0-9]{2,4})", $dFecIni, $aFecIni);`

Thank you very much in advance

Variables:

```
$dFecIni = date("o-m-d");
```

$dFecIni = str_replace("-","",$dFecIni);
$dFecIni = str_replace("/","",$dFecIni);

Echoes:

```
echo "<br /> dFecIni: " . $dFecIni; -> dFecIni: 20140808
```

echo "
 aFecIni: " . $dFecIni; -> aFecIni: 20140808

preg_match( "/([0-9]{1,2})([0-9]{1,2})([0-9]{2,4})/", $dFecIni, $aFecIni);
preg_match( "/([0-9]{1,2})([0-9]{1,2})([0-9]{2,4})/", $dFecFin, $aFecFin);

echo "
 aFecIni: " . $aFecIni[0]; -> aFecIni: 20140808

Then she did:

```
$date1 = mktime(0,0,0,$aFecIni[2], $aFecIni[1], $aFecIni[3]);
```

This is no my code so I am porting to another server and higher PHP version and having these errors...
Actually the error is that it is not inserting data on one table when it should, but I found that just before it uses this function, but even with the slashes is still not inserting

Comment: [link](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6270004/how-can-i-convert-ereg-expressions-to-preg-in-php)

Comment: what are $dFecIni & $aFecIni ? give inputs..

Comment: Ok, sorry, gonna edit

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Have a look at the [preg_match()](http://php.net/manual/en/function.preg-match.php),

```
int preg_match ( string $pattern , string $subject [, array &$matches [, int $flags = 0 [, int $offset = 0 ]]] )
```

In your case `$pattern` = `"/([0-9]{1,2})([0-9]{1,2})([0-9]{2,4})/"` 
The `$subject` is the text which you want to match, which I assume is `$dFecIni`. 
If you want to save the matches you provide the name of the variable where they are to be saved, `$aFecIni` for example,

The full function then become,

```
preg_match("/([0-9]{1,2})([0-9]{1,2})([0-9]{2,4})/", $dFecIni, $aFecIni);
```

Answer (score 0):

Just add slashes: `/`

```
"/([0-9]{1,2})([0-9]{1,2})([0-9]{2,4})/"
```