# Fatal error: Uncaught Error: Call to undefined function ereg_replace() PHP 7

Tags: php, php-7, ereg-replace

below code is giving me the fatal error in php 7

```
    $jquery_click_hook = ereg_replace("[^A-Za-z0-9]", "", strtolower($value['name']));
```

is there any way to make it compatible with php 7?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How can I convert ereg expressions to preg in PHP?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/6270004/1255289)

Answer (score 26, accepted):

Switch to [`preg_replace`<sup>*Docs*</sup>](http://php.net/preg_replace) and update the expression to use preg syntax (PCRE) instead of ereg syntax (POSIX) [where there are differences<sup>*Docs*</sup>](http://php.net/reference.pcre.pattern.posix) (just as it says to do in the manual for [`ereg_replace`<sup>*Docs*</sup>](http://php.net/ereg_replace)).

Your above code should be this way:

```
$jquery_click_hook = preg_replace("[^A-Za-z0-9]", "", strtolower($value['name']));
```

Comment: You should switch to mb_ereg_replace ; preg_replace has some issues with accented characters that I've not been able to resolve by changing locale, encoding etc.

Answer (score 5):

ereg_replace function was DEPRECATED in PHP 5.3.0, and REMOVED in PHP 7.0.0. So you must have to use [preg_replace()](http://php.net/manual/en/function.preg-replace.php) function instead of ereg_replace()