# eregi or preg from txt file in php

Tags: php, numbers, eregi

I have website selling charge cards, I use this code for selling to customers they verify the mobile number, manually (add a line every time) recently I use SMS service and numbers stored in text file in the site, how can remove these lines, and I get the numbers from the .txt files? (the numbers stored line by line in txt file)

```
if ($data[mobile] AND !eregi("^09512362982$", $data[mobile]))
if ($data[mobile] AND !eregi("^09527415120$", $data[mobile]))
if ($data[mobile] AND !eregi("^09532247462$", $data[mobile]))
if ($data[mobile] AND !eregi("^09535241919$", $data[mobile]))
if ($data[mobile] AND !eregi("^09535716327$", $data[mobile]))
$error .= "Mobile number not valid, please verify your number<br />";
```

Comment: You can use `|` for regex alterations. You can use `file` to get data from a file, `file_get_contents`, or `fread`. `^(09512362982|09527415120|etc.)$` 1 regex, not 1 per variation. Also seems like something a DB would be better for..

Comment: Lordie, what version of PHP are you using? `eregi()`'s deprecated in PHP 5.3.0, and REMOVED in PHP 7.0.0.

Comment: Good point @Fred-ii-, OP see http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6270004/how-can-i-convert-ereg-expressions-to-preg-in-php.

Comment: Plus, any reason you're not using a database for this? It's time to step into the 21st century. Text files are a lot of work.

Comment: The `eregi` is pretty much just doing `!=` anyway.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use `file` to read the contents of your text file into an array, and then `in_array` to see if the number is there.

```
if (!in_array($_data['mobile'], file('your_text_file.txt', FILE_IGNORE_NEW_LINES))) {
    $error .= "Mobile number not valid, please verify your number<br />";
}
```

Comment: Thank's for reply , 
But not work, 
Error 500

Comment: @php-Lover Sorry, I had a typo in the code (missing closing paren). I just corrected it.

Comment: Thank you for reply

Comment: thank you for reply 
but can't read the .txt file 
i use it on this method, can you help me where it the problem
*****

   if (!$data[mobile] AND !$data[mobile])
    $error .= 'You Must enter a mobile number‌<br />';
   if ($data[email] AND filter_var($data[email], FILTER_VALIDATE_EMAIL)== false)
    $error .= 'Email address incorrect<br />';
   if (in_array(file('s1.txt', $_data['mobile'],  FILE_IGNORE_NEW_LINES))) {
    // number is in file
} else {
    // it isn't
}

    $error .= "Please verify your number, by sending 454 to 520501<br />";
  }
  if($error)

Comment: In the code in that comment, you appended to the error after the if/else block from my code. You need to append to it in the if block. I updated the answer to show what I mean.

Comment: thank you again
i use the code, and not work, but i make some changes, and use this, the problem is , can't find the number fron txt file and match it if available or not.
numbers in txt file saved line by line:
0123456789
if ( file('s1.txt', in_array($_data['mobile'], FILE_IGNORE_NEW_LINES))) {
    $error .= "Mobile number not valid, please verify your number<br />";

Comment: i use the code :
`if (in_array($data[mobile], file('number.txt', FILE_IGNORE_NEW_LINES)))
    $error .= 'Mobile Number Not Verifed<br />';`

But there is problem, NOW  the numbers existing in TXT file get error and the numbers not existing pass it, On the contrary, I want.
What i must to do ? i hope you can help me

Comment: Use `!in_array` instead. I updated the answer.

Comment: Thank soooooooooooo MUCH it's WORK
thank you for help